# JavaScript automatic getter/setters (John Resig book)

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

I'm reading "[Pro JavaScript Techniques](http://jspro.org/)" by [John Resig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Resig), and I'm confused with an example. This is the code:

```
// Create a new user object that accepts an object of properties
function User( properties ) {
  // Iterate through the properties of the object, and make sure
  // that it's properly scoped (as discussed previously)
  for ( var i in properties ) { (function(){
  // Create a new getter for the property
  this[ "get" + i ] = function() {
    return properties[i];
  };
  // Create a new setter for the property
  this[ "set" + i ] = function(val) {
    properties[i] = val;
  };
})(); }
}

// Create a new user object instance and pass in an object of
// properties to seed it with
var user = new User({
  name: "Bob",
  age: 44
});

// Just note that the name property does not exist, as it's private
// within the properties object
alert( user.name == null );

// However, we're able to access its value using the new getname()
// method, that was dynamically generated
alert( user.getname() == "Bob" );

// Finally, we can see that it's possible to set and get the age using
// the newly generated functions
user.setage( 22 );
alert( user.getage() == 22 );
```

Now running that in the [Firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) console (on Firefox 3) throws that *user.getname()* is not a function. I tried doing this:

```
var other = User
other()
window.getname() // --> This works!
```

And it worked!

Why?

Doing:

```
var me = this;
```

seems to work a bit better, but when executing "getname()" it returns '44' (the second property)...

Also I find it strange that it worked on the window object without modification...

And a third question, what's the difference between PEZ solution and the original? (He doesn't use an anonymous function.)

Comment: I generally try to make code as simple as it can be. Thus I removed the anonymous function stuff where I didn't think it was needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started this post with the sole purpose of learning why that things happened, and I finally did. So in case there's someone else interested in the "whys", here they are:

**Why does 'this' changes inside the anonymous function?**

A new function, even if it is an anonymous, declared inside an object or another function, *always changes the scope*, in this case returning to the global scope ([window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)).

*Solution:* all stated in the post, I think the clearer is executing the anonymous function with *.call(this)*.

**Why does getname() always return the age?**

While the anonymous function gets executed right away, the getters/setters get executed for the first time when they are called. In that moment, the value of **i** will always be the last, because it has already iterated for all the properties... and it will always return properties[i] which is the last value, in this case the age.

*Solution:* save the `i` value in a variable like this

```
 for ( i in properties ) { (function(){ 
  var j = i
  // From now on, use properties[j]
```

Comment: "Solution: save the i value in a variable like this" (then "var j = i")
Be careful! This is misleading. I'm not sure whether or not it will work. What a closure basically does is to hold on to a reference to a particular variable from outside the function. (cont'd...)

Comment: (contd) You'll (usually) want separate closures to each refer to their own instances of a variable they are referring to. There is only one variable "i" in the for loop. I'm not sure whether "j" gets a new instance each loop iteration, or whether Javascript reuses it (in which case your soln fails)

Comment: The solution works. I've tested it and it's the only one that does what I've asked in the firs place.

Comment: interesting! then that says "j" gets a new instance each loop iteration. (at least for the implementation you're using, not sure if that's in the Javascript/ECMAScript spec, so just a warning as that might be implementation-dependent behavior e.g. could be different on different browsers)

Comment: Hmm, I repeat my warning. Here's a test that runs in Rhino or the Mozilla Spidermonkey Javascript shell:

var x = []; for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { var j = i; x.push(function() { return j; } ); }

x[0]() and x[9]() both return 9. (not 0 and 9)

Comment: OH, NEVER MIND! You are copying "var j = i" within the anonymous function that executes. That definitely creates a new instance. Javascript has function scope, not block scope.

Answer (score 5):

**I think it's best not to use the `new` keyword at all when working in JavaScript.**

This is because if you then instantiate the object **without** using the new keyword (ex: `var user = User()`) by mistake, *very bad things will happen...*reason being that in the function (if instantiated without the `new` keyword), the `this` will refer to the **global object**, ie the `window`...

So therefore, I suggest a better way on how to use class-like objects.

Consider the following example :

```
var user = function (props) {
    var pObject = {};
    for (p in props) {
        (function (pc) {
            pObject['set' + pc] = function (v) {
                props[pc] = v;
                return pObject;
            }
            pObject['get' + pc] = function () {
                return props[pc];
            }
        })(p);
    }
    return pObject;
}
```

In the above example, I am creating a new object inside of the function, and then attaching getters and setters to this newly created object.

Finally, I am returning this newly created object. *Note that the the `this` keyword is not used anywhere*

Then, to 'instantiate' a `user`, I would do the following:

```
var john = user({name : 'Andreas', age : 21});
john.getname(); //returns 'Andreas'
john.setage(19).getage(); //returns 19
```

**The best way to avoid falling into pitfalls is by not creating them in the first place**...In the above example, I am avoiding the `new` keyword pitfall (*as i said, not using the `new` keyword when it's supposed to be used will cause bad things to happen*) by **not using `new` at all.**

Comment: `new` is not evil if handled correctly, as [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful)

Comment: I've never really had this problem, as I never accidentally forget to use new.  I use naming conventions so I 100% know when I'm dealing with a class and when I'm not, i.e "let user = new adUserClass(apiData.rawUser);"  If it doesn't have Class on it's name in an import etc,  don't use new, pretty simple.

Answer (score 4):

Adapting Jason's answer, it works:

We need to make a closure for the values. Here's one way:

```
function bindAccessors(o, property, value) {
  var _value = value;
  o["get" + property] = function() {
    return _value;
  };
  o["set" + property] = function(v) {
    _value = v;
  };
}
```

Then the *User* constructor looks like this:

```
function User( properties ) {
  for (var i in properties ) {
    bindAccessors(this, i, properties[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: but calling the function on the window object(as I stated later) does work, I don't think that loop is the problem

Comment: Note to readers; Pablo is right. My answer is edited to reflect that.

Comment: Two comments:
1) thanks for the attribution (would be clearer to use my full username), now maybe someone could vote for my answer....? 8)

2) One change you made is very subtle: The getters and setters do NOT modify the properties hash, but rather the set of its values... (cont'd)

Comment: 2 cont'd) I can pass in a collection to the User constructor and the collection itself will NOT change. If that is a desired feature then you need to reference the properties array in the closure.

Comment: +1 for your answer. (I'd add +3 for pointing out the caveats with my answer if I could.)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this, which is more readable ([closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) are easy to learn once you get some practice):

```
function User( properties ) {
  // Helper function to create closures based on passed-in arguments:
  var bindGetterSetter = function(obj, p, properties)
  {
    obj["get" + p] = function() { return properties[p]; }
    obj["set" + p] = function(val) { properties[p]=val; return this; }
  };
  for (var p in properties)
    bindGetterSetter(this, p, properties);
}
```

I also added "return this;", so you can do:

```
u = new User({a: 1, b:77, c:48});
u.seta(3).setb(20).setc(400)
```

Answer (score 2):

As written in the OP, `this` in the loop is not referring to the User object as it should be. If you capture that variable outside the loop, you can make it work:

```
function User( properties ) {
  // Iterate through the properties of the object, and make sure
  // that it's properly scoped (as discussed previously)
 var me = this;
 for ( i in properties ) { (function(){
  // Create a new getter for the property
  me[ "get" + i ] = function() {
    return properties[i];
  };
  // Create a new setter for the property
  me[ "set" + i ] = function(val) {
    properties[i] = val;
  };
 // etc
```

Answer (score 2):

I just modified the code a bit like this.. This one should work.. This is same as setting me=this;  But a closure is required to set the value of each property properly, else the last value will be assigned to all properties.

```
    // Create a new user object that accepts an object of properties
    var User = function( properties ) {
      // Iterate through the properties of the object, and make sure
      // that it's properly scoped (as discussed previously)
      var THIS = this;
      for ( var i in properties ) { (function(i){
      // Create a new getter for the property
      THIS[ "get" + i ] = function() {
        return properties[i];
      };
      // Create a new setter for the property
      THIS[ "set" + i ] = function(val) {
        properties[i] = val;
      };
    })(i); }
    }

    // Create a new user object instance and pass in an object of
    // properties to seed it with
    var user = new User({
      name: "Bob",
      age: 44
    });

// Just note that the name property does not exist, as it's private
// within the properties object
alert( user.name == null );

// However, we're able to access its value using the new getname()
// method, that was dynamically generated
alert( user.getname() == "Bob" );

// Finally, we can see that it's possible to set and get the age using
// the newly generated functions
user.setage( 22 );
alert( user.getage() == 22 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the variable **i** is "closured" with the last value in the iteration ("age")? Then all getters and setters will access properties["age"].

Answer (score 0):

I found something that seems to be the answer; it’s all about context. Using the anonymous function inside the *for* loop, changes the context, making 'this' refer to the *[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)* object. Strange isn't it?

So:

```
function User(properties) {

  for (var i in properties) {

    // Here this == User Object
    (function(){
      // Inside this anonymous function, this == window object
      this["get" + i] = function() {
        return properties[i];
      };

      this["set" + i] = function(val) {
        properties[i] = val;
      };
    })();
  }
}
```

I don't know why that function changes the context of execution, and I'm not sure it should do that. Anyway, you can test it running the code there and trying *window.getname()*. It magically works! :S

The solution, as stated before, is changing the context. It can be done like [J Cooper said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377716/javascript-automatic-getter-setters-john-resig-book/377786#377786), passing the variable 'me' and making the function a closure or you can do this:

```
(function(){
    // Inside this anonymous function this == User
    // because we called it with 'call'
    this[ "get" + i ] = function() {
      return properties[i];
    };

    this["set" + i] = function(val) {
      properties[i] = val;
    };
 }).call(this);
```

Anyway, I'm still getting 44 when running 'getname'... What could it be?

Comment: I adapted Jason's tips on my answer. Now works. This was a good question. +1.