# Is JavaScript's "new" keyword considered harmful?

Tags: javascript

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377716/javascript-automatic-gettersetters-john-resig-book), a user pointed out that the `new` keyword was dangerous to use and proposed a solution to object creation that did not use `new`. I didn't believe that was true, mostly because I've used [Prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework), [Script.aculo.us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework) and other excellent JavaScript libraries, and everyone of them used the `new` keyword.

In spite of that, yesterday I was watching Douglas Crockford's talk at YUI theater and he said the exactly same thing, that he didn't use the `new` keyword anymore in his code ([Crockford on JavaScript - Act III: Function the Ultimate - 50:23 minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM&t=50m23s)).

Is it 'bad' to use the `new` keyword? What are the advantages and disadvantages of using it?

Comment: It is NOT 'bad' to use the new keyword. But if you forget it, you will be calling the object constructor as a regular function. If your constructor doesn't check its execution context then it won't notice that 'this' points to different object (ordinarily the global object) instead of the new instance. Therefore your constructor will be adding properties and methods to the global object (window). If you always check that 'this' is an instance of your object in the object function, then you won't ever have this problem.

Comment: I don't understand this. On one hand doug discourages use of `new`. But when you look at the YUI library. You have to use `new` everywhere. Such as `var myDataSource = new Y.DataSource.IO({source:"./myScript.php"}); `.

Comment: @aditya_gaur That's because if you need some initialization of an object, you'd have to hack up a `init` method if you're using the `Object.create` approach and call that after. Much easier to just use `new` which does both, sets the prototype chain and calls some initializer code.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed. Yes, it's likely to inspire some Crockford anti-fan venom but we are talking about popular advice to basically avoid a major language feature here. The mechanism that makes every JQuery object weigh almost nothing (where memory is concerned) involves using the 'new' keyword. Prefer factory methods to constantly invoking new, but don't drastically reduce your architectural options and performance potential by only using object literals. They have their place and constructors have their place. It is hands-down dated and lousy advice.

Comment: Rejecting an execution context that doesn't inherit from your object function is not a sensible approach.  You have then broken critical features like .call and .apply.

Comment: TLDR: Using `new` isn't dangerous. Omitting `new` is dangerous, and therefore [bad](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html). But in ES5 you can use [Strict Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/3345375), which protects you from that danger and many others.

Comment: This entire thread is outdated. The current best practice is to use ES6 modules and, for inheritance, ES6 classes. They’re in strict mode by default, which would imply that `this` won’t be `globalThis` in a function call, but it goes beyond that: classes cannot be used without `new` _at all_. Since ES6, the language has moved on to _encourage_ the use of `new`, as seen by newer constructors such as `Map` or `Set` not being usable (anymore) without `new`. Going against this doesn’t seem reasonable. Note that _old_ constructors, e.g. `new String`, `new Date`, `new Array`, have _old_ rules.

Answer (score 628, accepted):

Crockford has done a lot to popularize good JavaScript techniques. His opinionated stance on key elements of the language have sparked many useful discussions. That said, there are far too many people that take each proclamation of "bad" or "harmful" as gospel, refusing to look beyond one man's opinion. It can be a bit frustrating at times.

Use of the functionality provided by the `new` keyword has several advantages over building each object from scratch:

1. [Prototype inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186244/what-does-it-mean-that-javascript-is-a-prototype-based-language). While often looked at with a mix of suspicion and derision by those accustomed to class-based OO languages, JavaScript's native inheritance technique is a simple and surprisingly effective means of code re-use. And the `new` keyword is the canonical (and only available cross-platform) means of using it.
2. Performance. This is a side-effect of #1: if I want to add 10 methods to every object I create, I *could* just write a creation function that manually assigns each method to each new object... Or, I could assign them to the creation function's `prototype` and use `new` to stamp out new objects. Not only is this faster (no code needed for each and every method on the prototype), it avoids ballooning each object with separate properties for each method. On slower machines (or especially, slower JS interpreters) when many objects are being created this can mean a significant savings in time and memory.

And yes, `new` has one crucial disadvantage, ably described by other answers: if you forget to use it, your code will break without warning. Fortunately, that disadvantage is easily mitigated - simply add a bit of code to the function itself:

```
function foo()
{
   // if user accidentally omits the new keyword, this will 
   // silently correct the problem...
   if ( !(this instanceof foo) )
      return new foo();
   
   // constructor logic follows...
}
```

Now you can have the advantages of `new` without having to worry about problems caused by accidentally misuse.

John Resig goes into detail on this technique in his [Simple "Class" Instantiation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/) post, as well as including a means of building this behavior into your "classes" by default. Definitely worth a read... as is his upcoming book, [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/), which finds hidden gold in this and many other "harmful" features of the JavaScript language (the **chapter** on `with` is especially enlightening for those of us who initially dismissed this much-maligned feature as a gimmick).

### A general-purpose sanity check

You could even add an assertion to the check if the thought of broken code silently working bothers you. Or, as [some](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36866/some) commented, use the check to introduce a runtime exception:

```
if ( !(this instanceof arguments.callee) ) 
   throw new Error("Constructor called as a function");
```

Note that this snippet is able to avoid hard-coding the constructor function name, as unlike the previous example it has no need to actually instantiate the object - therefore, it can be copied into each target function without modification.

#### ES5 taketh away

As [Sean McMillan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful/383503?noredirect=1#comment7767833_383503), [stephenbez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful/383503?noredirect=1#comment21565658_383503) and [jrh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful/383503?noredirect=1#comment94711133_383503) noted, the use of `arguments.callee` is invalid in ES5's [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). So the above pattern will throw an error if you use it in that context.

#### ES6 and an entirely harmless `new`

ES6 introduces [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to JavaScript - no, not in the weird Java-aping way that old-school Crockford did, but in spirit much more like the light-weight way he (and others) later adopted, taking the best parts of prototypal inheritance and baking common patterns into the language itself.

...and part of that includes a safe `new`:

```js
class foo
{
  constructor()
  {
    // constructor logic that will ONLY be hit 
    // if properly constructed via new
  } 
}

// bad invocation
foo(); // throws, 
// Uncaught TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'
```

But what if you don't *want* to use the new sugar? What if you just want to update your perfectly fine old-style prototypal code with the sort of safety checks shown above such that they keep working in strict mode?

Well, as [Nick Parsons notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful/383503?noredirect=1#comment126932432_383503), ES6 provides a handy check for that as well, in the form of [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target):

```js
function foo()
{
  if ( !(new.target) ) 
     throw new Error("Constructor called as a function");
   
  // constructor logic follows...
}
```

So whichever approach you choose, you can - with a bit of thought and good hygiene - use `new` without harm.

Comment: if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) throw Error("Constructor called as a function");// More generic, don't require knowledge of the constructors name, make the user fix the code.

Comment: @some: Yes! If you're able to test and correct client code, then that would be an excellent choice.

Comment: @Shog9, thanks - excellent comment (learned something new)!

Comment: Shog could you edit the answer and give some detail about the advantages of 'new' you mention (speed and full use of prototypes)? I believe this is the most correct answer and I'd mark it as accepted answer if only that things were explained a bit more. Thanks :)

Comment: @Pablo - done. That said, i'm not sure you should accept an answer here; of course, that's up to you, but it seems like a bit of a subjective discussion.

Comment: The question was if it was 'bad' to use the new keyword, and the advantages and disadvantages of it. I believe your answer explains this in a very complete and concise way. I'm accepting it.

Comment: Regarding the check, couldn't you assume the global object is window, and do if (this == window) throw ..

Comment: @meandmycode: you *could* assume that. But then it would break if `window` *wasn't* the global object for some reason... or if `this` referenced some other context. Also, it's a bit distracting for an example, since the point of the test (whether implicit or explicit) is to verify that the context object is an instance of the constructor function itself.

Comment: The only reason for this is that arguments.callee is an 'expensive' call to make. I wonder if there are better ways to do this check more generically.. also I think initializing on something other than the global object is more intentional than erroneous.

Comment: If you're worried about performance - and actually have reason to be - then don't do the check at all. Either remember to use `new`, or use a wrapper function to remember it for you. I *suspect* that if you're at the point where it matters, you've already exhausted other optimizations such as memoization, so your creation calls will be localized anyway...

Comment: Sure, I understand the point regarding premature optimizations, it takes a lot of iterations to show the significant expense, '100,000 'function calls just breaks 1ms, when using callee that becomes 304ms.. whilst impresively expensive, its probably completely out of context with the body of the call, and how many times the call actually happens over a given period.

Comment: More than happy to bump this to +50 - rational arguments, clean fix to the "problem" everything you want in an answer here

Comment: @some Shouldn't that, ironically, be "new Error"?

Comment: @bzlm: interestingly, it doesn't actually matter - both `Error()` and `new Error()` return an instance of `Error`. However, given the context... it is funny.

Comment: @bzlm: LOL! Never saw that one comming! However: ECMA-262, 5th edition, 15.11.1 The Error Constructor Called as a Function:
When Error is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new Error object. Thus the function call Error(...) is equivalent to the object creation expression new Error(...) with the same arguments.

Comment: Using `arguments.callee` to check if you've been called with `new` may not be so good, since `arguments.callee` is not available in strict mode. Better to use the function name.

Comment: If I misspell an identifier, my code breaks. Should I not use identifiers? Not using `new` because you can forget to write it in your code is just as rediculous as my example.

Comment: @meandmycode No you cannot 100% assume it will be `window`. If using it on the server side, it won't be window. Your function could be called with anything else as `this` using `call` and `apply` so the correct test is to see if it's an instance of your constructor

Comment: A helpful convention I use (which I think came from Crockford himself): if it requires "new", capitalize it like a class name. `x = new Foo();` vs a regular function `x = foo();`

Comment: If you turn on strict mode, if you forget to use new you will get an exception when you try to use this: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/
That is easier than adding an instance of check to each constructor.

Comment: If you return a `self` variable instead of `this`, and change your first example to `var self = this instanceof foo ? this : new foo();`, then this will work with variadic functions while allowing `foo() instanceof foo` to return true.

Comment: This will prohibit anyone from using your constructor in a mixin, et al.  Better to check 'this' is not equal to the global object. `(function(ctx) {if (this === ctx) throw new Error("don't call as function");})(this);`

Comment: an update on this might be useful, at least I'm interested

Comment: What post neglects is that since ES5, there's `Object.create()`, so reasons 1 & 2 aren't applicable anymore

Comment: True enough, @CervEd... Though personally I'd avoid dropping `Object.create()` all over the place either - even moreso than `new`, you probably want to limit where you're creating non-trivial objects to avoid mistakes, especially if you have a lot of methods that depend on initialization. The real danger of `new` was always that it looked safer than it was; Object.create looks properly low-level and "dangerous" but does effectively the same thing.

Comment: @some ["The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of arguments.callee() in strict mode."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)

Comment: @jrh Some things has changed during the 10 years since I wrote that comment. At the time, 10 years ago, it was ES3 from 1999 that was valid. ES5 was published a year later, in December 2009 (as I mention in my own answer to this question). I'm not allowed to edit that comment that I made 10 years ago, and I'm very sorry that I at the time couldn't see into the future and see that it was going to change. I still can't predict the future.

Comment: @some yup, I know you can't edit it; maybe delete it and post a new comment?

Comment: If we were gonna update this, @jrh, it'd probably be more valuable to note in the answer that ES6 builds this pattern into the language itself via `class` - complete with a check for new-less invocation that throws an error. Maybe I'll get around to it.

Comment: @Shog9 Good point. If you get a chance I think an update like that would be very helpful.

Comment: @jrh No. It is still valid in normal mode. The comments already mentions ES5. In strict mode there is no reason to use arguments.callee. I do not want to erase every reference to history.

Comment: @some okay; up to you

Comment: Why would anyone forget to use "new"?  Coming from c/c++, c# etc, I don't think I'll ever forget to use new.

Comment: And now with ES6, we can use [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) to more reliably check if the constructor function was called with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Well, shucks @Nick - I guess after 12 years of neglect I might as well add a few pointers to current info :)

Answer (score 190):

I have just read some parts of [Crockford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford)'s book "[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford#Bibliography)". I get the feeling that he considers everything that ever has bitten him as harmful:

About switch fall through:

> I never allow switch cases to fall
> through to the next case. I once found
> a bug in my code caused by an
> unintended fall through immediately
> after having made a vigorous speech
> about why fall through was sometimes
> useful. (page 97, ISBN
> 978-0-596-51774-8)

About ++ and --:

> The ++ (increment) and -- (decrement)
> operators have been known to
> contribute to bad code by encouraging
> excessive trickiness. They are second
> only to faulty architecture in
> enabling viruses and other security
> menaces. (page 122)

About new:

> If you forget to include the *new*
> prefix when calling a constructor
> function, then *this* will not be
> bound to the new object. Sadly, *this*
> will be bound to the global object, so
> instead of augmenting your new object,
> you will be clobbering global
> variables. That is really bad. There
> is no compile warning, and there is no
> runtime warning. (page 49)

There are more, but I hope you get the picture.

My answer to your question: **No, it's not harmful.** but if you forget to use it when you should you could have some problems. If you are developing in a good environment you notice that.

In the 5th edition of ECMAScript there is support for [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode). In strict mode, `this` is no longer bound to the global object, but to `undefined`.

Comment: I completely agree. The solution: Always document how users have to instantiate your objects. Use an example and users will likely cut/paste. There are constructs/features in every language that can be misused resulting in unusual/unexpected behavior. It doesn't make them harmful.

Comment: There is a convention to always start constructors with an upper case  letter, and all other functions with a lower case letter.

Comment: I just realized that Crockford don't consider WHILE harmful... I don't know how many time I have created an infinitive loop because I have forgot to increment a variable...

Comment: Given two equivalent ways of doing something, you'd choose the more dangerous method, just because you can?

Comment: @Greg Dean: That was not was I said. I don't think new is harmful nor continue, ++, --, ==, != and labels on for, while and switch.

Comment: The question isn't whether or not new is harmful.  It's about its disadvantages/advantages.  There is one significant disadvantage, in that construction patterns that rely on it, can be harmful, when new is omitted.

Comment: 1 advantage as PEZ points out is that is is potentially more clear and familar

Comment: Same goes for ++, --. They express exactly what I intend in the clearest possible language. I love'em! switch fall throughs might be clear to some, but I'm weary about those. I use them when they are clearly more clear ('cuse the pun, couldn't resist).

Comment: My answer to Crockford: Programming is hard, lets go shopping.  Sheesh!

Comment: Very well said sir, very well said. Crockford's sky-is-falling approach isn't helping JS any.

Comment: I haven't read his book. But I think you should learn from your mistakes. If ++ bites him then avoiding ++ **could** be right, for him. Of course, I'm all for Toyotas "five whys" so I would probably dig deeper and find why it **really** bit me.

Comment: From page 112: "The increment and decrement operators make it possible to write in an extremely terse style. In languages such as C, they made it possible to write one-liners that could do string copies:" (cont...)

Comment: for(p = src, q= dest; !*p; p++, q++) *q=*p; "They also encourage a programming style that, as it turns out, is reckless. Most of the buffer overrun bugs that created terrible security vulnerabilities were due to code like this."

Comment: I disagree with some parts of what Crockfords says, and agrees with some other parts, like eval.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: Yeah. I liked the accepted answer there, good to keep in mind when discussing "evil" features... ;-)

Comment: Part of good programming is writing code that's easy to maintain, especially by less experienced developers. Even if you're sure you'll never forget to use `new` (in which case you're more confident than I am), are you sure your entire team is immune to that mistake? I, too, think Crockford is a little over-careful, but this is one place where I definitely agree with him.

Comment: @JustinMorgan A lot of things has happened since the answer was written about 6 years ago, for example we now have `strict mode` (see update to my answer) where `this` will be `undefined` instead of the global object if `new` wasn't used when it was expected, and therefore you will get an exception if it is used. I have forgotten to use `new`, created infinite loops with `while`, forgot `break` in `switch`, called functions with wrong parameters or in the wrong order and a whole bunch of other errors… But most of those errors was found while testing the code or in beta testing.

Comment: I haven't read his book, but I would 100% agree with Crockford that those specific language features you mention cause problems, *that could be avoided when designing a language*, hence are "bad". `switch fall-through` in particular I've always hated. I mean, its been years, maybe decades, since I've forgotten a "break", but I hate how verbose it makes a simple bit of code. In hindsight, `C` could have done the *opposite* - added a keyword that you use *when you want to fall through to the next case* - and then all the languages that followed would have mimicked that. So much cleaner :)

Comment: FWIW, as somebody who's done a lot of C, I don't like `for(p = src, q= dest; !*p; p++, q++) *q=*p;` but that's not typically how I use ++ and --. I can think of a lot of innocuous cases where `i++` and `i--` couldn't possibly do any harm and are crystal clear; besides it's not like `i+=1` or `i = i + 1` is all that much better. I think Doug generalized a bit too much with ++ and --. I do agree with him on `switch` fall through, though.

Comment: Also there are niche scenarios where you might want your object's this context to be bound to the global variable so not using new could be intentional.  I often make global utility helpers this way.  However it's probably cleaner code to just use the window object so it's obvious.

Answer (score 93):

JavaScript being a dynamic language, there are a zillion ways to mess up where another language would stop you.

Avoiding a fundamental language feature such as `new` on the basis that you might mess up is a bit like removing your shiny new shoes before walking through a minefield just in case you might get your shoes muddy.

I use a convention where function names begin with a lowercase letter and 'functions' that are actually class definitions begin with an uppercase letter.  The result is a really quite compelling visual clue that the 'syntax' is wrong:

```javascript
var o = MyClass();  // This is clearly wrong.
```

On top of this, good naming habits help.  After all, functions do things and therefore there should be a verb in its name whereas classes represent objects and are nouns and adjectives without any verb.

```javascript
var o = chair() // Executing chair is daft.
var o = createChair() // Makes sense.
```

It's interesting how Stack Overflow's syntax colouring has interpreted the code above.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking the same thing about the syntax coloring.

Comment: Once I forgot to type the word 'function'. The word should be avoided at all costs. Another time I didn't use curly braces in a multi-line if/then statement. So now I don't use curly braces and just write one-line conditionals.

Comment: *"This is clearly wrong"*. Why? For my classes (which simply do `if (! this instanceof MyClass) return new MyClass()`) I actually prefer the `new`-less syntax. Why? Because *functions* are more generic than *constructor functions*. Leaving out `new` makes it easy to change a constructor function into a regular function... Or the other way around. Adding in `new` makes the code more specific than it needs to be. And hence less flexible. Compare with Java where it's recommended to accept `List` instead of `ArrayList` so the caller can choose the implementation.

Comment: I don't know about JavaScript, but for Java, [the (new) syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) definitely expects Java code conventions to be followed, incl. casing of identifiers and space before and after the equal sign.

Answer (score 42):

I am newbie to JavaScript so maybe I am just not too experienced in providing a good view point to this. Yet I want to share my view on this "new" thing.

I have come from the C# world where using the keyword "new" is so natural that it is the factory design pattern that looks weird to me.

When I first code in JavaScript, I don't realize that there is the "new" keyword and code like the one in [YUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library) pattern and it doesn't take me long to run into disaster. I lose track of what a particular line is supposed to be doing when looking back the code I've written. More chaotic is that my mind can't really transit between object instances boundaries when I am "dry-running" the code.

Then, I found the "new" keyword which, to me, "separates" things. With the *new* keyword, it creates things. Without the *new* keyword, I know I won't confuse it with creating things unless the function I am invoking gives me strong clues of that.

For instance, with `var bar=foo();` I don’t have any clues as what *bar* could possibly be.... Is it a return value or is it a newly created object? But with `var bar = new foo();` I know for sure *bar* is an object.

Comment: Agreed, and I believe the factory pattern should follow a naming convention like makeFoo()

Comment: +1 - the presence of 'new' gives a clearer statement of intent.

Comment: This response is kind of weird, when almost everything in JS is an object. Why do you need to know for sure that a function is an object when all functions are objects?

Comment: @JoshuaRamirez The point is not that `typeof new foo() == "object"`. It's that `new` returns an instance of `foo`, and you know you can call `foo.bar()` and `foo.bang()`. However that can easily be mitigated by using [JsDoc's @return](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReturns) Not that I'm advocating for procedural code (avoiding the word `new`)

Comment: @JuanMendes Hmm... Your post made it seem to me that you liked new because of its explicit keyword in your code base. I can dig that. That's why I use a module pattern. I'll have a function called createFoo or NewFoo or MakeFoo, doesn't matter as long as it's explicit. Inside that I declare variables which are used as closures inside of an object literal that is returned from the function. That object literal ends up being your object, and the function was just a construction function.

Answer (score 40):

Another case **for** new is what I call [Pooh Coding](http://old.robowiki.net/cgi-bin/robowiki?PoohCoding). [Winnie-the-Pooh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnie-the-Pooh) follows his tummy. I say go **with** the language you are using, not **against** it.

Chances are that the maintainers of the language will optimize the language for the idioms they try to encourage. If they put a new keyword into the language they probably think it makes sense to be clear when creating a new instance.

Code written following the language's intentions will increase in efficiency with each release. And code avoiding the key constructs of the language will suffer with time.

And this goes well beyond performance. I can't count the times I've heard (or said) "why the hell did they do **that**?" when finding strange looking code. It often turns out that at the time when the code was written there was some "good" reason for it. Following the Tao of the language is your best insurance for not having your code ridiculed some years from now.

Comment: +1 for the Pooh Coding link - now i need to find excuses to work this into my conversations...

Comment: LOL! I have years of experience in that particular field and I can assure you that you'll find no difficulties. They often call me Pooh over at robowiki.net. =)

Comment: Don't know if you'll ever see this comment, but that Pooh Coding link is dead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. We migrated robowiki.net to a new wiki last week and the old content is unreachable at the moment. I'll hurry up with making those old links work.

Answer (score 25):

I wrote a post on how to mitigate the problem of calling a constructor without the *new* keyword.

It's mostly didactic, but it shows how you can create constructors that work with or without *new* and doesn't require you to add [boilerplate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code) to test *this* in every constructor.

*[Constructors without using "new"](http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/constructors-without-using-new.html)*

Here's the gist of the technique:

```
/**
 * Wraps the passed in constructor so it works with
 * or without the new keyword
 * @param {Function} realCtor The constructor function.
 *    Note that this is going to be wrapped
 *    and should not be used directly
 */
function ctor(realCtor) {
  // This is going to be the actual constructor
  return function wrapperCtor() {
    var obj; // The object that will be created
    if (this instanceof wrapperCtor) {
      // Called with new
      obj = this;
    } else {
      // Called without new. Create an empty object of the
      // correct type without running that constructor
      surrogateCtor.prototype = wrapperCtor.prototype;
      obj = new surrogateCtor();
    }
    // Call the real constructor function
    realCtor.apply(obj, arguments);
    return obj;
  }

  function surrogateCtor() {}
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
// Create our point constructor
Point = ctor(function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
});

// This is good
var pt = new Point(20, 30);
// This is OK also
var pt2 = Point(20, 30);
```

Comment: avoiding ``arguments.callee`` is awesome!

Comment: I maintained a collection of similar Crockford-inspired utilities, and found that it always had me running to find the implementations when I start a new project.  And this wraps such a fundamental part of programming: object instantiation.  All this work, just to enable haphazard instantiation code?  I appreciate the ingenuity of this wrapper, honestly, but it just seems to engender careless coding.

Comment: @joecoder I did mention this was for didactic purposes only, I do not subscribe to this paranoia style of coding. However, if I was writing a class library, then yes I would add this feature in a way that is transparent to callers

Answer (score 22):

The rationale behind not using the *new* keyword, is simple:

By not using it at all, you avoid the pitfall that comes with accidentally omitting it.  The construction pattern that [YUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library) uses, is an example of how you can avoid the new keyword altogether:

```
var foo = function () {
    var pub = { };
    return pub;
}
var bar = foo();
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
function foo() { }
var bar = new foo();
```

But by doing so you run risk of someone forgetting to use the **new** keyword, and the **this** operator being all [FUBAR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FUBAR#Adjective). As far as I know, there isn't any advantage to doing this (other than you being used to it).

At The End Of The Day: **It's about being defensive.**  Can you use the new statement? Yes. Does it make your code more dangerous? Yes.

If you have ever written C++, it's akin to setting pointers to NULL after you delete them.

Comment: No. With "new foo()" some properties are set on the returned object, like constructor.

Comment: It's the same, I just omitted any initialization for brevity.

Comment: So, just to make this clear: you shouldn’t use “new” because you might forget it? You are kidding, right?

Comment: @Bombe : in other languages forgetting "new" would result in an error. In Javascript, it just keeps on trucking. You can forget, and never realise. And simply looking at erroroneous code *wont* be obvious at all whats going wrong.

Comment: @Greg: I don't see how the first technique allows for use of prototype chains - object literals are great, but throwing away the performance and other advantages provided by prototypes out of fear seems a bit silly.

Comment: @Bombe - You should use "new" because you (and anyone that uses your code) will never make a mistake?  You are kidding, right?

Comment: @Shog - Great point, +1 for the John Resig link too

Comment: Thanks Greg, I think I know why I intuitively took side *for* new when I saw this question. I'm always *offensive*. The glass is half full, whatever those engineers say.

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, it's not really whether you should use new, it's whether you should write your constructors so they need to be called with new. Is that correct?

Comment: If you use an initial capital letter for constructors (recommended anyway for visually distinguishing), it's simple to statically check for invalid constructor calls (missing new).  For example, jshint uses newcap (set to true) for this.  Given this easy "compile-time" check, I see no reason to forbid new.

Comment: @KentFredric This is like not using `==` because if we used `=` it would result in a silent error.

Comment: @GregDean Sorry for such a late comment, but a linting tool is a much better solution than littering the code with paranoia checks, as Matthew Flaschen mentioned.

Answer (score 20):

I think "new" adds clarity to the code. And clarity is worth everything. It is good to know there are pitfalls, but avoiding them by avoiding clarity doesn't seem like the way for me.

Answer (score 15):

#### Case 1: `new` isn't required and should be avoided

```
var str = new String('asd');  // type: object
var str = String('asd');      // type: string

var num = new Number(12);     // type: object
var num = Number(12);         // type: number
```

#### Case 2: `new` is required, otherwise you'll get an error

```
new Date().getFullYear();     // correct, returns the current year, i.e. 2010
Date().getFullYear();         // invalid, returns an error
```

Comment: It should be noted that in case 1, calling the constructor as a function only makes sense if you are intending type conversion (and do not know if the hull object has a conversion method, such as `toString()`).  In all other cases, use literals.  *Not* `String('asd')`, but simply `'asd'`, and *not* `Number(12)`, but simply `12`.

Comment: @PointedEars One exception to this rule would be `Array`: `Array(5).fill(0)`  is obviously more readable than `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined].fill(0)` and `(var arr = []).length = 5; arr.fill(0);`

Comment: @YoYoYonnY My statement was made in context of case 1 of the answer, which refers to the use of `new` with constructors for object types corresponding to *primitive* types. The literal that you are suggesting is _not_ equivalent to the `Array` call (try `0 in …`), and the rest is a syntax error :) Otherwise you are correct, although it should be noted as well that `Array(5)` can be ambiguous if you consider *non-conforming* implementations (and therefore an *emulated* `Array.prototype.fill(…)`).

Comment: Note that `Date` has special rules to differentiate between `new` being used vs. not being used. It’s kind of an outlier. Also, all of these constructors are part of the oldest language specifications. Newer language features are more behaved. All of the answers here need to be updated or deleted…

Answer (score 12):

Here is the briefest summary I could make of the two strongest arguments for and against using the `new` operator:

#### Arguments against `new`

1. Functions designed to be
   instantiated as objects using the
   `new` operator can have disastrous
   effects if they are incorrectly
   invoked as normal functions.  A
   function's code in such a case will
   be executed in the scope where the
   function is called, instead of in
   the scope of a local object as
   intended.  This can cause global
   variables and properties to get
   overwritten with disastrous
   consequences.
2. Finally, writing `function Func()`,
   and then calling `Func.prototype`
   and adding stuff to it so that you
   can call `new Func()` to construct
   your object seems ugly to some
   programmers, who would rather use
   another style of object inheritance
   for architectural and stylistic
   reasons.

For more on this argument check out [Douglas Crockford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford)'s great and concise book *[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford#Bibliography)*.  In fact, check it out anyway.

#### Arguments in favor of `new`

1. Using the `new` operator along with
   [prototypal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) assignment is fast.
2. That stuff about accidentally
   running a constructor function's
   code in the global namespace can
   easily be prevented if you always
   include a bit of code in your
   constructor functions to check to
   see if they are being called
   correctly, and, in the cases where
   they aren't, handling the call
   appropriately as desired.

See [John Resig's post](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/) for a simple explanation of this technique, and for a generally deeper explanation of the inheritance model he advocates.

Comment: An update on the against arguments: #1 can be mitigated by using `'use strict';` mode (or the method in your link) #2 Has synatic sugar in **ES6**, however the behavior is the same as before.

Answer (score 9):

I agree [with PEZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful/383446#383446) and some here.

It seems obvious to me that "new" is self descriptive object creation, where the [YUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library) pattern Greg Dean describes is *completely obscured*.

The possibility someone could write `var bar = foo;` or `var bar = baz();` where *baz* isn't an object creating method seems *far* more dangerous.

Answer (score 6):

I think *new* is evil, not because if you forget to use it by mistake it might cause problems, but because it screws up the inheritance chain, making the language tougher to understand.

JavaScript is [prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) object-oriented. Hence every object *must* be created from another object like so: `var newObj=Object.create(oldObj)`. Here *oldObj* is called the prototype of *newObj* (hence "prototype-based"). This implies that if a property is not found in *newObj* then it will be searched in *oldObj*.  *newObj* by default will thus be an empty object, but due to its prototype chain, it appears to have all the values of *oldObj*.

On the other hand, if you do `var newObj=new oldObj()`, the prototype of *newObj* is *oldObj.prototype*, which is unnecessarily difficult to understand.

The trick is to use

```
Object.create=function(proto){
  var F = function(){};
  F.prototype = proto;
  var instance = new F();
  return instance;
};
```

It is inside this function and it is only here that *new* should be used. After this, simply use the *Object.create()* method. The method resolves the prototype problem.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not wild about this technique - it doesn't add anything new, and as your answer illustrates it can even end up being a crutch. IMHO, understanding prototype chains and object instantiation is crucial to understanding JavaScript... But if it makes you uncomfortable to use them directly, then using a helper function to take care of some details is fine, so long as you remember what you're doing. FWIW: a (somewhat more useful) variation on this is part of the ECMAScript 5th ed. std, and already available in some browsers - **so you should be careful not to blindly redefine it!**

Comment: BTW: I'm not sure why you made this CW, but if you want to re-post it with the formatting corrections I made, be careful to avoid that checkbox...

Comment: Unnecessarily difficult to understand? `var c = new Car()` is the same as doing `var c = Object.create(Car.prototype); Car.call(c)`

Answer (score 0):

In my not-so-humble opinion, "new" is a flawed concept in 2021 JavaScript. It adds words where none are needed. It makes the return value of a function/constructor implicit and forces the use of *this* in the function/constructor. Adding noise to code is never a good thing.

```
// With new
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
}
let point = new Point(0, 0)
```

Vs.

```
// Without new
function Point(x, y) {
    return { x, y }
}
let point = Point(0, 0)
```