# Mixin inheritance pattern of javascript lose Closure feature

Tags: javascript

All, I knew the traditional way to define a javascript OOP Object. here is the example .

```
var TField=function(jData)
{
   this.id=jData.id;
   this.name=jData.name;
   this.attributes=jData.attributes;
   TField.prototype.render=function(){
      alert(jData.id);
   };
};
```

We can found the `TField.prototype.render` know what is the value of the `jData` whenever it is called, It is because of the feature of the `Closure`.

But now I just tried to implement the inheritance in javascript .and I found the recommended way is `Mixin pattern`.
Here is the code what I had done so far .

```
TChildField.prototype.render=function(){
      alert('TChildField render.');
      //Can not utilize the parameters of the constructor. like jData
};


var TField=function(jData)
{
   this.id=jData.id;
   this.name=jData.name;
   this.attributes=jData.attributes;

};

TField.prototype.render=function(){
      alert('TField render.');
};

var TChildField=function(jData)
{
    TField.call(this,jData)
}

var tobj={id:"1",name:"test",attribute:{}};
TChildField.prototype=Object.create(TField.prototype)
TChildField.prototype.render=function(){
      alert('TChildField render.');
};
var c= new TChildField(tobj);
alert(c.id);
alert(c.name);
```

well ,It works fine without problem. But My problem is I found I can't utilize the parameter `jData` of the constructor of the `TChildField` just like TField. I knew I can define `this.Data=jData` so that I can use it in the `TChildField.prototype.render`, But I don't want it to be as a property. and the worst thing of it is losing the benifit of the `Closure`, Is there any way to make it ? Or something I didn't know ?thanks.

Comment: You probably mean "mixin", not "maxin".

Comment: Sorry for the wrong typo. fixed it .thanks.

Comment: See the following question for an idea on how to simulate protected class members: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703698/javascript-module-pattern-protected-members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need this encapsulation for? What's wrong with setting `this.Data=jData`? It's simple and it solves your problem. And why the worst thing is losing the benefit of the closure? Actually closures should be avoided as they may lead to very funky problems (memory leaks?).

Comment: I think that's the point of the question: how can you make `jData` only available to the methods of the class.

Comment: @IgorZinov'yev You can't without making it visible outside.