# Pass function as parameter in object oriented javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am very new to this and it is reflected on the way i put the title.

May be the example below can illustrate my question better.

I have a an object called model.

```
var Modal = new function(){
    this.id = 'modal_id';
    this.title = 'Modal title';
    this.content = 'Modal content';
    this.display = function(){
        return '<div class="popup">' + this.title + ' ' + this.content + '<br><button id="button"></div>';
    };
}
```

The object is called with this for example:

```
Modal.title = 'My New title';
Modal.content = 'My New content';
Modal.display();
```

But let's say i want to have an event for the button the trigger different action, how can i define the function when calling the object when button is clicked?

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    // different action here
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to call when its clicked? Modal.display()?

Comment: It can be any action. but i want such a way that i can have custom action for that click and can be defined when calling it. One Modal can trigger action A while another Modal can trigger another different action when the button is clicked.

Comment: [Don't ever use `new function() { … }`!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10406552/1048572)

Comment: Can you give me a valid reason? @Bergi

Comment: @davidlee: Please read the answers to the question I linked to. If you have any objections to the reasons I gave there, please comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you should do to make this work the best.

- Pass in a function to be assigned
- Return a real DOM element instead of messing about with building HTML from strings.

  ```
  var Modal = function(onClickHandler){
    this.id = 'modal_id';
    this.title = 'Modal title';
    this.content = 'Modal content';
    this.display = function(){
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "popup";
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.title));
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.content));
        div.appendChild(document.createElement("br");

        var button = document.createElement("button");
        // Assign a unique ID here if you need.

        // You could also use addEventListener as well
        button.onclick = onClickHandler;
        button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("CLICK!"));


        div.appendChild(button);
        return div;
    };
  }

  Modal.prototype.close = function(){
    console.log("Close it");
    console.log(this);
  }


  var newDiv = new Modal(function() {
    alert("I was clicked");
  });
  ```

Comment: how to call the object with function?

Comment: It has this error: TypeError: Modal is not a constructor

Comment: Sorry, had a typo .. there was an `new` in front of `function` that shouldn't have been there.

Comment: One last question @Jememy, may i know how can i call a specific action by the function? like Modal.close()? provided i define the close function in the object.

Comment: Added a call example.  You really should read this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809914/oo-javascript-constructor-pattern-neo-classical-vs-prototypal