# What's the difference between these two function declarations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have some doubt about this two javascript case:

```
function some() {
    this.some2 = function() {//this is associated with own object(Correct?)
        console.log('some2');
    }
}

var __s1 = new some();
__s1.some2();//Allright, this do the work;
//some().some2();//This not work
```

This declaration type has a technical name? Object patterns maybe?

Another similiar case is this:

```
function some() {
    return {
        some2: function() {
            console.log('some2');
        }
    }
}

var __s2 = new some();
__s2.some2(); // Right, this work;
some().some2(); //Also work ... Ok, "some()" returns a object that contain
                //the some2().
```

This second case, also has a technical name?

What's best case between they?

Comment: doesnt answer your question but relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809914/oo-javascript-constructor-pattern-neo-classical-vs-prototypal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is using Prototypes. Calling `new some()` creates a new object, sets `this` to that object during the function execution, and returns the new object. Calling `some()` is meaningless in this case because there will be nothing to set `this` to when `some` is being executed (though the function still does get executed.)

The second case is a normal function that returns an object. There is no technical name for it.

Similar to the second case, is something called Closures. You could do,

```
function some() {
    return function() {
        console.log('some2');

    }
```

and then do

```
var s3= some();
s3() //prints some2
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet you associate a function to a property named `some2`.

In JS functions are first class object so they can have additional properties, when you call `some2` you actually use object delegation on `some` function.

In your second snippet you are using `return` to return a new completely object at every call which has a new function `some2`. When you initiate a new object based (`new some()`) you actually return new objects with new functions and do not referencing to a single one as in your first snippet.