# Javascript Inheritance Pseudo-classical approach

Tags: javascript, inheritance

**Error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined
```

---

I was wondering if anyone can help me out, I was able to successfully implement inheritance using the Prototypal pattern, but when I try to code it using the Pseudo-classical (shown below) pattern - I Keep failing.

Can anyone direct me as to what I am doing wrong? Also what are the best practices when in comes to implementing inheritance in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance.

```
+ function test() {

    var obj = function(objType, objClass) {
        this.objType = objType;
        this.objClass = objClass;
    };

    obj.prototype.objCreate = function(objWidth, objHeight, objBackground) {
        this.element = document.createElement(obj.objType);
        document.getElementsByName('body')[0].appendChild(this.element);
        this.element.className = this.objClass;
        this.element.style.width = objWidth;
        this.element.style.height = objHeight;
        this.element.style.backgroundColor = objBackground;
    };

    var box1 = new obj('div', 'box1');

    box1.objCreate('200px', '200px', 'red');

}();
```

Comment: You want `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` **TagName**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error you're getting is because you're using `document.getElementsByName` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName` as I mentioned in the comments.

As far as inheritance goes, the topic has been already extensively covered on this forum.. I'll direct you to:

[Pseudo-classical vs. "The JavaScript way"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791131/pseudo-classical-vs-the-javascript-way?rq=1)
[JavaScript Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486825/javascript-inheritance)

Comment: Thanks! can't believe I missed that!