# How to change frame source without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a Template Site, i want to change the content of the IFrame
based on the link clicked in javascript,
but the error i get is if i change the 'src' attribute of the iframe
the page gets reload.

So my question is

how to change iframe content without reloading the Page? below is my code

// HTML part

```
<li class="inside first">
   <a href='JavaScript:void(0);' onclick='clicked(0);' title="HOME">HOME</a>
</li>
<li class="inside">
   <a  href=''onclick='clicked(1); ' title="PRODUCTS">PRODUCTS</a>
</li>
<li class="inside">
   <a  href='' onclick='clicked(2); ' title="SOLUTIONS">SOLUTIONS</a>
</li>
<li class="inside">
    <a  href=''  onclick='clicked(3); 'title="SERVICES">SERVICES</a>
</li>
<li class="inside">
    <a  href='' onclick='clicked(4); ' title="SUPPORT">SUPPORT</a>
</li>

<div id="mainContent">
    <iframe 
           src=''
           width="100%"
           height="100%"
           name='content'
           id='content'>&nbsp;
    </iframe>
</div>
```

//Javascript part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var index=0;
   var link_list= new Array('homepage.html','product.html','solution.html',
            'services.html','support.html','event.html',
             'partner.html','company.html');

   var frame=document.getElementById('content');

   frame.src=link_list[index];

   function clicked(key)
   {

       // The following line is redirecting the page
       frame.src=link_list[key];
       return false;
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just write hrefs for those links and add attribute `target="content"`.

This can be done w/o javascript at all.

Comment: `<a href='' target='content.html' >Link </a>`  is opening in new tab

Comment: Erm... `target='content'` w/o `.html`. It's the name of your frame. Whilst `href` attribute should be set to corresponding hrefs.

Answer (score 1):

Your `link_list` is wrong, JavaScript is case-sensitive, it's `new Array()`, not `new array()`:

```
var link_list = new Array(...);
```

Use the array literal [`[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094723/what-is-array-literal-notation-in-javascript-and-when-should-you-use-it#1094734) and you're fine:

```
var link_list = ['homepage.html','product.html','solution.html',
            'services.html','support.html','event.html',
             'partner.html','company.html'];
```

If you check your browser's JavaScript error console it's easy to find such errors:

```
[09:16:09.208] array is not defined @ file:///.../temp.html:34
```

Comment: Also single quots are not a part of HTML. Switch them to double quots.

Comment: @Teemo: What are you talking about? Both HTML and JavaScript support both single and double quotes.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Have I missed something? Since when this HTML-support has been available?

Comment: @Teemu: Since [HTML 2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866#section-3.2): "The value of the attribute may be \[..\] A string literal, delimited by single quotes or double quotes and not containing any occurrences of the delimiting character". See also [HTML4 attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).

Comment: HTML is a successor of SGML, so it always supported that. See "3.2.4. Attributes" of the first RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866