# JavaScript "Check All" with Radio and Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I've got a function in JS that check all my checkboxes in a form:

```
function CheckAll(chk){
    for (i = 0; i < chk.check.length; i++)
        if (chk.All.checked==true){
            chk.check[i].checked = true;
            chk.check[i].disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            chk.check[i].disabled = false;
            chk.check[i].checked = false;
        }
}
```

I've recently added some `radio` buttons to my form, and my question is: **will this function activate *ALL* my radio buttons too** (I know that only one radio button can be selected, but I'm not sure how this works in a script like that..)?

Here you can find my form code:

```
<form name='MyForm'>
    <b>This is my Simple Form</b></br>
    </br>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='ONE' checked='checked' />ONE<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='TWO' />TWO<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='THREE' />THREE<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='FOUR' />FOUR<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='FIVE' />FIVE<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='SIX' />SIX<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='SEVEN' />SEVEN<br/>
    <script>
        document.write("</br>");
        var count
        var check_value = new Array()
        check_value[0] = "001"
        check_value[1] = "002"
        check_value[2] = "003"
        check_value[3] = "004"
        for(count in check_value){
            var checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='"+check_value[count]+"' />"
            document.write(checkbox + check_value[count] + "  ");
        }
        document.write("<input type='checkbox' name='All' value='All' onClick='CheckAll(document.MyForm);' /> All");
    </script>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type=button value='Ok' onClick='foo(document.MyForm);'>
</form>
```

If this don't work as I want, how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you test it ? If not, why ?

Comment: Because at the moment I can't modify a servlet, because I don't have the source code, but only the .class. The foo function will send some parameters to it after a little data elaboration, but before sending them I wanted to know how that works.

Comment: You cannot check more than one radio so only the last will be activated Also you pass the wrong object. Pass this.form.parameter

Comment: Use `;`. No `document.write()`. Cannot see function call. Ahhhh!

Comment: @Amberlamps what do you mean?

Comment: @abierto: I am sorry. All I was saying is that your code needs a lot of improvement. Use a semicolon `;` at the end of every line, do not use `document.write()`, use literals instead of `new Array()`... This is totally unrelated to your question. I am just saying.

Comment: @abierto You should put a `;` after your statements. In most case you have no problem omitting them but the rules are complex so put them.

Comment: @Amberlamps why I should not use `document.write()` and `new Array()`?

Comment: @abieto: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094723/what-is-array-literal-notation-in-javascript-and-when-should-you-use-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing is as simple as that : http://jsfiddle.net/yk9uD/

Content :

```
<form name='MyForm'>
    <b>This is my Simple Form</b></br>
    </br>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='ONE' checked='checked' />ONE<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='TWO' />TWO<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='THREE' />THREE<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='FOUR' />FOUR<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='FIVE' />FIVE<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='SIX' />SIX<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='parameter' value='SEVEN' />SEVEN<br/>
    <script>
      function CheckAll(chk){
  for (i = 0; i < chk.check.length; i++) {
        if (chk.All.checked==true){
            chk.check[i].checked = true;
            chk.check[i].disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            chk.check[i].disabled = false;
            chk.check[i].checked = false;
        }
}
}
        document.write("</br>");
        var count;
        var check_value = new Array()
        check_value[0] = "001"
        check_value[1] = "002"
        check_value[2] = "003"
        check_value[3] = "004"
        for(count in check_value){
            var checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='"+check_value[count]+"' />"
            document.write(checkbox + check_value[count] + "  ");
        }
        document.write("<input type='checkbox' name='All' value='All' onClick='CheckAll(document.MyForm);' /> All");
    </script>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type=button value='Ok' onClick='foo(some var);'>
</form>
```

And the answer to the question is : No, it won't select all radio buttons.

The reason is that your code iterates only over inputs whose name is `check` :

```
for (i = 0; i < chk.check.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Then, in my case, the first one will stay checked? Nothing more?

Comment: The CheckAll function only modifies the input whose name is "check", so it can't touch the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't work for radio buttons. The name given for radio button is different than that of checkbox. So, your function does not touch radio buttons. But if you have created an event for class providing the radio buttons and the checkboxes same class name, the function would also include the radio buttons. But in that case, only the last radio button will be checked. In fact, all radio button gets checked while the code executes. But when the radio button with same name is found again, the previous checked attribute is removed and the checked attribute comes to current node.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check which radio box in checked then you can use following code.

```
$('.myclass input[name="radio_box_name"]:checked').val())
```