# How to determine if parameter is an Array or an Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a prototype like this;

```
LocalDataEngine.prototype.ExecuteNonQuery = function (query) { }
```

And I call this prototype within two different argument like below;

By using object array;

```
var createQueries = new Array();
createQueries.push(new SQLiteQuery(""));
createQueries.push(new SQLiteQuery(""));
createQueries.push(new SQLiteQuery(""));

new LocalDataEngine().ExecuteNonQuery(createQueries);
```

By using only object;

```
new LocalDataEngine().ExecuteNonQuery(new SQLiteQuery(""));
```

My question is, how can I determine `query` argument in prototype is object array or object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array

Comment: + this feels like bad design to me. Just make two functions `executeOneQuery` and `executeManyQueries`.

Comment: You're right, but I dont want to change existing design.

Comment: Regarding the design, why don't you make `ExecuteNonQuery` variadic, i.e. accept multiple arguments where each one is a query. Then always iterate over all arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `instanceof`:

```
% js
> [] instanceof Array
true
> {} instanceof Array
false
```

It will work flawlessly if you are not using frames (which is probably a bad idea anyway). If you are using frames and ECMAScript 5, use `Array.isArray`:

```
> Array.isArray({})
false
> Array.isArray([])
true
```

See the duplicate question linked by thg435 for additional solutions.

Comment: I couldn't understand your syntax

Comment: This can fail in multi-frame DOM environments. It’s more safe to use `Object.prototype.toString`, see here: http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/

Comment: @MehmetInce: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1094723/309483) for an explanation of the literal array syntax. As you can see, there are reasons to prefer it.

Comment: frames = bad. iFrames = still very common (f.ex video embeds).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
if (query instanceof Array) {
    return 'array';
} else if (query instanceof Object) {
    return 'object';
} else {
    return 'scalar';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( yourObj) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array!' );
}
```

Comment: +1. This is also what jQuery uses under the hood for `$.isArray()`.