# Determine if JSON array or single object

Tags: node.js

I am new in Node.Js.
I am trying to make simple API.

I want to save users into MongoDB. I get request as JSON.
I have this route. But it doesn't work.
How can I determine is jsonObject an object or array?

```
router.route('/users')
.post(function(req, res) {

    var jsonObject = req.body;


    if(!jsonObject.isArray){
        var user = new User();

        user.name = req.body.name;
        user.phone = req.body.phone;

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({message: 'User created!'});
        });
    }
    //Array of users
    else{
        for(var i = 0; i < jsonObject.length; ++i){
            var object = jsonObject[i];
            var user = new User();
            user.name = jsonObject[i].name;
            user.phone = jsonObject[i].phone;
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                res.json({message: 'Users created!'});
            });
        }
    }
})
.get(function (req, res) {
    User.find(function (err, users) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

I want to use this two types of requests:

```
{
"name": "ALONE",
"phone": "43141"
}
```

Array:

```
    [
  {
    "name": "User1",
    "phone": "43141"
  },

  {
    "name": "User2",

  }
]
```

Comment: Use `typeof varName`

Comment: no, that would return `'object'` in both cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if parameter is an Array or an Object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771713/how-to-determine-if-parameter-is-an-array-or-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could check for length

- var x = ["foo", "bar"]; alert(x.length);
- var y = {"foo":"bar"}; alert(y.length);

Or you parse the response to check if it a json at all: http://www.json.org/js.html

cheers, Jo