# Using unshift function with multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to use the unshift function with a MD array, and I cannot get it to work accordingly.

I am using shift okay and it does what is needed like expected but unshift does not.

Below is the array which I am using:

```
[ [ '487', 'RINGING' ], [ '477', 'RINGING' ] ]
```

When I try and do an unshift on it it displays the following:

```
[ [ '487', 'RINGING' ], [ '477', 'RINGING' ], 2 ]
```

I simply need to move 477 array to the beginning like so:

```
[ [ '477', 'RINGING' ], [ '487', 'RINGING' ]]
```

The code I am using:

```
var channelArrStatus = [ [ '477', 'RINGING' ], [ '487', 'RINGING' ]];

function monitor_channel(event, channel) {
if (event.device_state['state'] === "RINGING") {
      var name = "User_487";
      var status = "NOT_INUSE"
      var index = 0;
      if (channelArrStatus.length === 0) {
        var chanar = new Array(name, status);
        channelArrStatus.push(chanar);
      } else {
        var found = false;
        for (var i in channelArrStatus) {
          var channelArrStatusElem = channelArrStatus[i];
          if (channelArrStatusElem[0] === name) {
            index = i;
            found = true;
            if (channelArrStatus[index][1] !== "DND") {
              channelArrStatus.push(channelArrStatus.unshift());
              setTimeout(function () {
                channelArrStatus[index][1] = status;
              }, 10000);
            }
          }   
        }
      }
    }
```

I cant get it to move an array to the beginning of the array as highlight above using unshift.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mc3utj2x/4/)

Comment: `unshift` adds an element to the beginning of an array, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @giannisf thats what am trying to do but I cant get it to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call [`.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) prepends nothing and returns the length of the array - `2` in your case - and that's the value you are pushing.

You either want

```
channelArrStatus.push(channelArrStatus.shift()); // no un-
```

or

```
channelArrStatus.unshift(channelArrStatus.pop());
```

---

That said, you should [use literal notation instead of the `Array` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1094723/1048572) and [avoid `for in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572).

Comment: I dont want to shift it to the end of the array again I need to move it to the beginning, I have added a JS fiddle to the question to demonstrate this using `channelArrStatus.unshift(channelArrStatus.pop());` but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
 channelArrStatus.push(channelArrStatus.unshift());
```

You are adding the length of array to the **end** of the array.
If you want to add an element to the start of array, just call `unshift`.

```
channelArrStatus.unshift(element);
```

Comment: Having no joy with it I have also tried the answer below I have updated with a JS fiddle if that helps.