# how to find numbers whose sum is equal to the number of occurrences of the function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

On input functions we take not sorted array of numbers and the number that can be obtained by adding the numbers from the given array.

It is necessary to return the first found numbers whose sum is equal to the number obtained from the function argument.

I almost managed to get what I needed, but due to the addition of conditions, I drove myself into a trap and now I can not deduct a negative number from zero without adding another if that will bring the second number to a positive view so that you can subtract from zero and then translate him back.

(in the second function call, I manage to add 0 and -6 only during the last cycle, when we subtract 0 from -6)

How can I subtract a number from zero and reduce the logic?

```js
function sum_pairs(ints, s){
  let arr=[];
    
    
     for(let i=0; i<ints.length; i++){
      for(let j=1; j<ints.length; j++){
       
        if(s>=0){
          if(ints[i]+ints[j] === s){
           arr.push(ints[i], ints[j]);
           return arr
          }
      } else{
     /*   if(ints[i] === 0 ){
           ints[j] = Math.abs(ints[j])
         } */
         if(ints[i]-ints[j] === s){
              arr.push(ints[i], ints[j]);
              return arr
           }
       }
       
      }     
     }
    
   
   
    
  
}

console.log(sum_pairs([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8)) // [1,7]
console.log(sum_pairs([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6)) // [0,-6]
console.log(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)) // [3,7]
```

Comment: Hey, I'm unsure what you expect the function to do? Are you trying to get all combinations that can sum up to 8 (example 1)?

Comment: Is this a homework or job interview assignment?

Comment: @dschu Hey! I am trying to return a combination of numbers whose sum is equal to 8 in first example

Comment: @AndreasPizsa The task found on the Internet to improve skills

Comment: Um `0 + (-6)` *is* `-6` ? You don't need the if/else ...

Comment: @JonasWilms ohh, thanks i forgot about that expression

Comment: Note that `console.log(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 1], 10)) // [3,7]` incorrectly returns `[5,5]` (matching `5` twice)

Comment: @Drop Please see my answer below, including a fix for the aforementioned bug. If you find my answer helpful, I appreciate your upvote and accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasPizsa yea, thanks! its very help me to understand my problem and fix it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Algebra

> How can I subtract a number from zero and reduce the logic?

As @Jonas Wilms mentioned, adding a negative number *A* to another number *B* will result in *subtracting* A from B.

```
let A = 1
let B = -6
A + B
// <- -5
// because (1 + -6) => (1 - 6) = -5
```

You can thus remove `if(s>=0){` entirely.

## Algorithm

You want to find the first pair of numbers from `ints` whose sum is `sum`.

It's correct in principle to iterate through `ints`, as you do, and then iterate again to find a matching number.

### Fix 1: always return correct pairs

#### Problem

The original algorithm will sometimes return false pairs. Take for example

```
sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 1], 10))
```

This will incorrectly return `[5,5]`:

```
s = 10
i = 1
j = 1
ints[i] + ints[j] === s // true because ints[1] = 5
```

#### Solution

Make sure that you never add the number at the same array index.

We do this by adding

```
if (j === i) continue;
```

```js
function sumPairsSimple(ints, sum) {
  for (let i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < ints.length; j++) {
      if (j === i) continue;
      if (ints[i] + ints[j] === sum) {
        return [ints[i], ints[j]]
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(sumPairsSimple([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8)) // [1,7]
console.log(sumPairsSimple([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6)) // [0,-6]
console.log(sumPairsSimple([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 1], 10)) // [3,7]
```

Note also that I’m returning an [Array literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094734/199263) to keep the code clean, short and easily readable.

### Fix 2: Optimization

The second fix is an optimization. Notice that the two `for` loops both start at `0` and iterate through all the `ints`.

#### Problem

Let's assume the following call:

```
sum_pairs([5, 4, 8, 10], 18)
```

This result in the following additions:

```
ints[0] + ints[1]
ints[0] + ints[2]
ints[0] + ints[3]

ints[1] + ints[0] // same as ints[0] + ints[1]
ints[1] + ints[2]
ints[1] + ints[3]

ints[2] + ints[0] // same as ints[0] + ints[2]
ints[2] + ints[1] // same as ints[1] + ints[2]
ints[2] + ints[3]
```

As you can see in this code above, there are quite some redundancies.

#### Solution

In this step, we're going to remove those redundancies and win some CPU cycles :)

We’r going to only check the elements *after* the current one, because we know that we’ve already the ones *before* it:

```
ints[0] + ints[1]
ints[0] + ints[2]
ints[0] + ints[3]

ints[1] + ints[2]
ints[1] + ints[3]

ints[2] + ints[3]
```

This saves us 3 redundant computations.

In code, we do this by starting the inner loop with `j = i + 1`:

```js
function sumPairsOptimized(ints, sum) {
    for(let i=0; i<ints.length; i++) {
        for(let j=i+1; j<ints.length; j++) {
            if(ints[i] + ints[j] === sum) {
                return [ints[i], ints[j]]
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(sumPairsOptimized([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8)) // [1,7]
console.log(sumPairsOptimized([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6)) // [0,-6]
console.log(sumPairsOptimized([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 1], 10)) // [3,7]
```

Comment: i found little bug in that algorithm.
if we take some array like this sum_pairs([10,5,2,3,7,5], 10)
Then we take sum 5+5, not 3+7
Because we take first element and plus with all next elements

Comment: From my understanding of the question, `[5,5]` would be the correct result given that the input contains [*,5, *, *, *, 5]. `5+5` is the first pair that equals `10`. Why do you think `[3,7]` should be the first matching pair, @Drop?

Comment: sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5],         10)
   5 + 5 = 10, indices: 1, 5;  


    3 + 7 = 10, indices: 3, 4 - entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
== [3, 7] @AndreasPizsa

Comment: Ah, I see. I now see that this example was even stated in the question. So the rule is to find the first _neighbouring_ numbers then? How does that go together with `sum_pairs([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8))` returning `[1,7]`, given that they are further apart? Do neighbouring numbers have priority, but then fall back to any match?

Comment: At sum_pairs([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8)) only 1,7 give  on sum 8

Comment: sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4],         6)    4 + 2 = 6, indices: 0, 2 * ;   3 + 3 = 6, indices: 1, 3;  2 + 4 = 6, indices: 2, 4
  * entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
== [4, 2]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I subtract a number from zero?

```
  0 - someNumber
```

> and reduce the logic?

1) `arr` is not needed, just return an array literal.

2) You don't need the `if` / `else` to distinguish negative / positive results, `0 + (-6)` is `-6` so no need for the if / else.

3) you don't need the elements indices, so just iterate without to clean things up.

```
 function sumPairs(nums, expected) {
   for(const a of nums) {
     for(const b of nums) {
       if(a + b === expected) {
          return [a, b];
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a combination of [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) if you only need the first matching result.

```js
function findSummands(numbers, equalTo) {
  let summands = []
  numbers.some(lhs => numbers.find(rhs => {
    if (lhs + rhs === equalTo) {
      summands.push(lhs, rhs)
      return true
    }
    return false
  }))
  return summands
}

const test1 = findSummands([1, 4, 8, 7, 3, 15], 8)
const test2 = findSummands([1, -2, 3, 0, -6, 1], -6)
const test3 = findSummands([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)

console.log({test1, test2, test3})
```