# Mdn reference for using hasOwnProperty with bracket notation

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am using the following code in javascript:

```
let group = false;
let internalId = "someString";
let appliedTo = "someOtherString";
let keyToGroupBy = true === group ? internalId : appliedTo;

if(grouped.hasOwnProperty([keyToGroupBy])) {
   ...
}
```

Could someone provide a reference as to why using the brackets with keyToGroupBy is working preferably in mdn?
Is this considered a hack(works by chance) or it is something commonly used?
is there a better way to do the same?

Comment: where do you see this example?

Comment: Converting a one element array to a string gives the one element converted to string. I didn't check, but i assume `hasOwnProperty` just uses `toString`. Example: `"" + [{ toString: () => "hi" }] === "hi"`

Comment: PS: just as a fun additional fact (not really relevant), you can modify this behavior, by making the property access "join" find a function other than the default `Array.prototype.join` first. I checked, `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` does a `ToPrimitive` and a `ToString` in sequence, so to make both fail, lets use an object that refuses to be a string: `let x = ["hi"]; var o = { toString: () => o }; x.join = () => o; ({}).hasOwnProperty(x);` and e.g. on FF, i get the error "TypeError: can't convert x to string". Welcome to javascribbidies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bracket notation" is not [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation). What you've defined there is [an array literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094723/what-is-array-literal-notation-in-javascript-and-when-should-you-use-it) for an array with one element:

```js
let group = false;
let internalId = "someString";
let appliedTo = "someOtherString";
let keyToGroupBy = true === group ? internalId : appliedTo;

console.log(Array.isArray([keyToGroupBy]))
```

So, it "works" because the properties of objects are either strings or symbols. Since you're not supplying a Symbol, it's going to be turned into a string. And when you do that with an array, the result is...a string equal to the first element:

```js
let group = false;
let internalId = "someString";
let appliedTo = "someOtherString";
let keyToGroupBy = true === group ? internalId : appliedTo;

let arr = [keyToGroupBy];

console.log(String(arr) === arr[0]);
console.log(String(arr));
```

Turning an array [to a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) involves internally calling [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and since there are no other values, no separator would be produced and nothing will be added to the single string that is in the array.

So, you're doing a rather roundabout way of...just checking for the string.

> Is this considered a hack(works by chance)

It's mostly a hack. It's not quite *abusing* the rules of type conversion but certainly skirting them.

> or it is something commonly used?

No, it's not. There is no reason to wrap strings into arrays...and then convert them to a string again if all you need is a string in the first place.

> is there a better way to do the same?

Yes, simply don't have an array literal anywhere: `grouped.hasOwnProperty(keyToGroupBy)`