# Why does JavaScript allow accessing an object's property using an array of length 1, as if the array was just the single element itself?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

See this example:

```
> map = { 5: 'five' }
> map[5] 
'five' // Makes sense
> arr = [5]
> map[arr]
'five' // Does not make sense
> arr = [5,6,7]
> map[arr]
undefined // I'm cool with that
```

So when I access an object's property with an array of length 1, it behaves as if I simply input the single element instead of the array. But when the array's length is anything but 1, it will produce the expected behavior.

What is the purpose of this behavior? To me this would simply make things harder for a developer to find a bug in their code.

Comment: Because `[5].toString() === "5"`. `map[{toString: () => "5"}]` would give the same result too. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066846/keys-in-javascript-objects-can-only-be-strings.

Comment: Converting an array to a string is equivalent to `array.join(",")`

Comment: It's basically [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061627/mdn-reference-for-using-hasownproperty-with-bracket-notation/60061794#60061794) - the array would be stringified and gets turned to a single `"5"`

Comment: Actually `map[[[[[5]]]]] == "five"` Yeah, javascript sometimes just sucks.

Comment: You forgot to mention that `"five" == {[[5, 6, 7]]: 'five'}[[5, 6, 7]]` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object index is not a string or Symbol, it's converted to a string as if by its `toString()` method.

`array.toString()` performs the equivalent `array.join(",")`.

So

```
map[arr]
```

is equivalent to

```
map[arr.join(",")]
```

If the array has one element, joining it simply returns that one element converted to a string, so it's equivalent to

```
map[arr[0].toString()]
```

and that explains your first result.

But in your second example, it returns the string `"5,6,7"` and there's no property with that name in the object.