# "Use the array literal notation []" for var os_map = {}

Tags: javascript, jslint

I don't understand why I get the error message when I run JSLint with a JavaScript file.

I get the message var `os_map = {}; Problem at line 28 character 36: Use the array literal notation [].` if I run [this code](http://en.wikipedia.org/skins-1.5/common/mwsuggest.js) in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). The options for the JSLint as the following.

```
/*jslint onevar: true, browser: true, undef: true, nomen: true, eqeqeq: true, plusplus: true, bitwise: true, regexp: true, strict: true, newcap: true, immed: true */
```

Claiming object (, which is `{}`) should be okay, but JSLint suggets to use an empty array (, which is `[]`)

: I found an answer. I was wrong. There's nothing wrong with `var os_map = {}`. The code was shown in an error message because I did not use `"require strict";`. I got the error message wrong. Thanks for answering my questions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The offending line:

```
var os_autoload_inputs = new Array('searchInput', 'searchInput2',
                                   'powerSearchText', 'searchText');
```

JSLint does [not expect](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#new) to see `new Array` constructor, you should use []  instead:

```
var os_autoload_inputs = ['searchInput', 'searchInput2',
                                   'powerSearchText', 'searchText'];
```

Why? :

1, Crockford doesn't like `new`.

2, The `Array` object could be overridden:

```
Array = {};
new Array(); // TypeError: Array is not a constructor
```

3, Usage inconsistencies, e.g.:

```
var a = new Array(5); // empty 5 elements array
var b = [5]; // 1 element array containing the 5 number on index 0
```

See also:

- [What’s the difference between “Array()” and “[]” while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr)
- [What’s wrong with var x = new Array();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885156/whats-wrong-with-var-x-new-array)

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
var a = new Array(5);
```

for this:

```
var a = new [].constructor(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

My read of line 28 in [that code](http://en.wikipedia.org/skins-1.5/common/mwsuggest.js) is:

```
var os_autoload_forms = new Array('searchform', 'searchform2', 'powersearch', 'search' );
```

...where it would indeed be appropriate to use the literal array syntax:

```
var os_autoload_forms = ['searchform', 'searchform2', 'powersearch', 'search' ];
```

It should be saying the same thing about line 27, though.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I mistook the error message. Please read the "Update" in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem at line 16 character 32: 
Use the array literal notation []. 
if I run this code in JSLint. 
The options for the JSLint as the following.

just do

var arrayName= [];