# how to load a 2d array in js?

Tags: javascript

Okay, I'm trying to load a 2d array and having some problems. Here's my code:

```
var blockSize = 30;

var level = new Array(new Array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), new Array(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0));

var blockArray = new Array(1);
blockArray[0] = new Array(1);

function readLevel() {
    for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {
            var tempImg = new Image();
            tempImg.src = "images/block.png";
            blockArray[i][j] = new block(i * blockSize, j * blockSize, level[i][j], false, false, tempImg);

            //throw('blockArray['+i+']'+j+'] = ' + level[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my error:

```
Firebug's log limit has been reached. 0 entries not shown.      Preferences  
blockArray[i] is undefined
[Break On This Error] blockArray[i][j] = new block(i *...level[i][j], false, false, tempImg);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: When you write `new Array(1)` are you trying to create an empty 1-element array, or a 1-element array that contains `1`? Unless you want to create an empty, `n`-element array, there's no reason to use the `new Array()` constructor; just use array literals instead. Ex., your `new Array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)` call would simply become `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`.

Comment: Better: `var level = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your outer loop, on `i`, will go from `0`..`1` (inclusive). You're never setting `blockArray[1]` to anything, and so it's undefined. So your `blockArray[i][j] = ...` line will fail because you can't index into an undefined value (`blockArray[i]` is undefined when `i` = `1`).

I'm not entirely sure what your code is meant to do, but this should get you close, anyway:

```
var blockSize = 30;

var level = [
                [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
            ];

var blockArray = [];

function readLevel() {
    for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
        blockArray[i] = []; // Create the second level for this index
        for (var j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {
            var tempImg = new Image();
            tempImg.src = "images/block.png";
            blockArray[i][j] = new block(i * blockSize, j * blockSize, level[i][j], false, false, tempImg);

            //throw('blockArray['+i+']'+j+'] = ' + level[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've also ditched the `new Array(n)` syntax in favor of array literal syntax. I think it's clearer for what you're doing here.

It's important to realize that JavaScript doesn't really have arrays, and it certainly doesn't have 2D arrays. JavaScript "arrays" are really just objects that give special treatment to a class of property names (ones consisting entirely of digits) and that have a special `length` property. (And, of course, they have all the functions they inherit from `Array.prototype`.) [More here.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)

Comment: @CyanPrime: No worries, glad that helped. I've added a link at the end of the answer that may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add between your two for-loops these line

```
blockArray[i] = new Array();
```

to create the second level array.

```
function readLevel() {
    for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
        blockArray[i] = new Array();
        for (var j = 0; j < level[i].length; j++) {
            [etc]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or `blockArray[i] = [];` Why do you guys keep using this other notation? `[]` is clearly better.

Comment: [See this Q & A.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936047/jslint-use-the-array-literal-notation-for-var-os-map)

Comment: It's more terse and readable, especially for nested arrays. Also, there is this issue with the number and type of arguments: `new Array(3)` and `new Array(3, 3)` and new `Array('3')` generate unexpectedly different results `[]` and `[3, 3]` and `['3']` respectively. Professional JavaScript programmers avoid the `new Array()` notation.