# What's wrong with this javascript? Array not defined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reference

What's wrong with this code?

```
var divarray = document.getElementById("yui-main").getElementsByTagName("div");
var articleHTML = array();
var absHTML;
var keyHTML;
var bodyHTML = array();
var i = 0;
for ( var j in divarray) {
    if(divarray[i].className == "articleBody"){
  alert("found");
  articleHTML = divarray[i];
  break;
 }
 bodyHTML[i] = '';
 if(articleHTML[i].className == "issueMiniFeature"){continue;}
 if(articleHTML[i].className == "abstract"){absHTML = articleHTML[i]; continue;}
 if(articleHTML[i].className == "journalKeywords"){keyHTML = articleHTML[i]; continue;}
 bodyHTML[i] = articleHTML[i];
 i++;
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
ReferenceError: array is not defined
```

I am using Google Chrome if it helps any.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not php - you should use

```
var variable_name = new Array()
```

or even better

```
var variable_name = []
```

Answer (score 8):

That's not how to declare variables as an empty array. You should be using:

```
var articleHTML = [];
```

[See this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885156/whats-wrong-with-var-x-new-array/885194#885194) for reasoning of using this method instead of `new Array()`

Answer (score 2):

It's `[]` in ECMAScript; this isn't PHP. The interpreter is right - `array` **is not** defined, which is why you're getting that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var articleHTML = new Array();
```

Answer (score 2):

Note! Javascript IS case sensitive you have to use upper-case A in word Array.

```
var myarr = new array(); //THIS IS WRONG! and will result in error not defined
```

So these are the correct ways:

```
var myarr = new Array(); //THIS IS CORRECT (note the "big" A) :)
var myarr = []; //and this is correct too
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var articleHTML = array();
```

and

```
var bodyHTML = array();
```

do

```
var articleHTML = [];
```

and

```
var bodyHTML = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define

```
var divarray = new Array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need to use var six times, you can do:

```
var divarray = document.getElementById("yui-main").getElementsByTagName("div"),
    articleHTML = [],
    absHTML = [],
    keyHTML = [],
    bodyHTML = [],
    i = 0;
```

Which works just as well as your six vars but looks much nicer.

Also there are a number of compelling reasons not to use new in instantiate an array (besides []; is much shorter than new Array();)

Comment: having fun reading your own code that way - totally difficult to determine where variables are first declared. see python.

Comment: ruby is also that way for shame