# Javascript Object push() function

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript object (I actually get the data through an ajax request):

```
var data = {};
```

I have added some stuff into it:

```
data[0] = { "ID": "1"; "Status": "Valid" }
data[1] = { "ID": "2"; "Status": "Invalid" }
```

Now I want to remove all objects with an invalid status (but keep everything the ordering same):

```
var tempData = {};
for ( var index in data ) {
    if ( data[index].Status == "Valid" ) {
        tempData.push( data );
    }
}
data = tempData;
```

In my mind, all of this should work, but I am getting an error that `tempData.push` is not a function.  I understand why it isn't the same as an array, but what could I do otherwise?

Comment: It looks like you should just use an array

Comment: instead of tempData.push( data ); write this tempData[index] = data. So you will not lose the order to.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

[`push()` is for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), not [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods), so use the right data structure.

```
var data = [];
// ...
data[0] = { "ID": "1", "Status": "Valid" };
data[1] = { "ID": "2", "Status": "Invalid" };
// ...
var tempData = [];
for ( var index=0; index<data.length; index++ ) {
    if ( data[index].Status == "Valid" ) {
        tempData.push( data );
    }
}
data = tempData;
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it.  Don't forget to change the `for...in` loop, too.

Comment: @MattBall my bad! I am not really that adept at SO review and stuff! :)

Comment: Push is for array,Is there any way to add an array to an object?

Comment: What about associative array?

Comment: @KinnardHockenhull I'm sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: change tempData.push( data ) to tempData.push( data[index] ) to avoid pushing the entire array.

Answer (score 26):

Objects does not support push property, but you can save it as well using the index as key,

```js
var tempData = {};
for ( var index in data ) {
  if ( data[index].Status == "Valid" ) { 
    tempData[index] = data; 
  } 
 }
data = tempData;
```

I think this is easier if remove the object if its status is invalid, by doing.

```js
for(var index in data){
  if(data[index].Status == "Invalid"){ 
    delete data[index]; 
  } 
}
```

And finally you don't need to create a var temp –

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 6):

You must make `var tempData = new Array();`

Push is an Array function.

Comment: Why `new Array()` and not `[]`?

Comment: [] is an alternative (shortcut) to create new array. It can be made with [] and with new Array().

Comment: `[]` is the primary way of creating arrays, the other are alternatives and can even be overwritten.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885156/whats-wrong-with-var-x-new-array for a discussion of why `new Array()` is evil

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp   new Array is regular array. Where [] defined as primary?

Comment: @Esailija I agree that not everything w3schools says is true and best practices. But I always knew that new Array() is a way to create arrays in JS and [] is a shortcut. Best practices is not a subject that OP asked about and it can be discussed for a long time. Anyway, [] is safer, new Array(100) is faster.

Comment: @Esailija your test is not what I'm talking about...check this: http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs/2

Comment: @AlexDn those are not equivalent. `var a = new Array(100)` is the equivalent of `var a = []; a.length = 100;`. `new Array(100)` does not do anything but set the `length` to `100`

Comment: @Esailija ok, I'm not choose the correct equivalent, but this is a modified test...still, new Array(100) is faster then []; [].length = 100;   http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs/2

Comment: @AlexDn sure it is, and easier to write. But there are only very, very rare cases where you want `Array(x)` instead of `[]`. And `[]` is faster.

Comment: @Esailija I agree, that's very rare case, but for OP question, the both versions will work. Best practices again, totally another discussion :) Why I wrote new Array and not [], just because it's the first thing that up in my mind...:)

Answer (score 5):

Javascript programming language supports functional programming paradigm so you can do easily with these codes.

```
var data = [
    {"Id": "1", "Status": "Valid"},
    {"Id": "2", "Status": "Invalid"}
];
var isValid = function(data){
    return data.Status === "Valid";
};
var valids = data.filter(isValid);
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this one might help you.

```js
let data = [];
data[0] = { "ID": "1", "Status": "Valid" };
data[1] = { "ID": "2", "Status": "Invalid" };

let tempData = [];

tempData= data.filter((item)=>item.Status!='Invalid')

console.log(tempData)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    tempData.push( data[index] );
```

I agree with the correct answer above, but.... your still not giving the index value for the data that you want to add to tempData.  Without the [index] value the whole array will be added.

Comment: Please describe how to solve the problem in detail. Thanks.

Comment: This would be to correct the accepted answer from Matt Ball. As we are looping through data, we should only push data[index], not data entirely.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that REALLY you get object from server and want to get object on output

```
Object.keys(data).map(k=> data[k].Status=='Invalid' && delete data[k])
```

```js
var data = { 5: { "ID": "0", "Status": "Valid" } }; // some OBJECT from server response

data = { ...data,
  0: { "ID": "1", "Status": "Valid" },
  1: { "ID": "2", "Status": "Invalid" },
  2: { "ID": "3", "Status": "Valid" }
}

// solution 1: where output is sorted filtred array
let arr=Object.keys(data).filter(k=> data[k].Status!='Invalid').map(k=>data[k]).sort((a,b)=>+a.ID-b.ID);
  
// solution2: where output is filtered object
Object.keys(data).map(k=> data[k].Status=='Invalid' && delete data[k])
  
// show
console.log('Object',data);
console.log('Array ',arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla actually shows you how to handle objects with push by chaining push to the call method:

"push is intentionally generic, and we can use that to our advantage. Array.prototype.push can work on an object just fine, as this example shows.

Note that we don't create an array to store a collection of objects. Instead, we store the collection on the object itself and use call on Array.prototype.push to trick the method into thinking we are dealing with an array—and it just works, thanks to the way JavaScript allows us to establish the execution context in any way we want.

```
const obj = {
  length: 0,

  addElem(elem) {
    // obj.length is automatically incremented
    // every time an element is added.
    [].push.call(this, elem);
  },
};

// Let's add some empty objects just to illustrate.
obj.addElem({});
obj.addElem({});
console.log(obj.length);
// → 2
```

Note that although obj is not an array, the method push successfully incremented obj's length property just like if we were dealing with an actual array."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because data.push only works with array, not object.

So here is what you can do:

```
var data = {};

data[0] = { "ID": "1"; "Status": "Valid" }
data[1] = { "ID": "2"; "Status": "Invalid" }

var tempData = {};
for ( var index in data ) {
if ( data[index].Status == "Valid" ) {
    tempData[index] = data[index];
}
}
data = tempData;
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Do :

```
var data = new Array();
var tempData = new Array();
```

Comment: Why `new Array()` and not `[]`?

Comment: note the difference between new Array(); and new Array; You should be able to answer such questions instead of telling about alternatives..