# Updating existing key value pair throws <Object> has no method 'push' error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update an existing JavaScript object with a new key value and also update an existing value like so

```
$.each(eventsData, function() {
    if (this.ID== "eb_0") {
        this.push({
            author_name: "John Seeds" //new key value pair to be added.
            title: newTitle_var //to be updated
        });
    }
});
console.log(this.eventsData)
```

My Object looks something like this.

```
[
    Object { ID="eb_0", title="DayY", Date=Date, more...}, 
    Object { ID="eb_1", title="DayZ", Date=Date, more...},
    Object { ID="eb_2", title="DayX", Date=Date, more...}          
]
```

Currently console.log outputs the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'
```

Could anyone help me figure this out please?

Comment: You should use a variable instead of `this` because `push()` works with array object.

Comment: it appears that `this` isn't what you are expecting it to be. Also, your object is actually an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Object push() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925820/javascript-object-push-function)

Comment: @Ejay: Considering the accepted answer, it turns out `push` wasn't necessary at all, so the suggested duplicate is not helpful.

Comment: the expected output of both problems looked a lot alike to me. I've retracted the vote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
$.each(eventsData, function () {
    if (this.ID == "eb_0") {
        this.author_name = "John Seeds"; //new key value pair to be added.
        this.title = newTitle_var; //to be updated
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you..I have no idea what I was thinking with the whole .push thing. Thank you again.