# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when combining arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

When pushing an array's contents to another array I get

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" error
>   in this snippet.

```
var order = new Object(), stack = [];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) == 0){ order[0].push(a[i]); }
    if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) > 0){ order[1].push(a[i]); }
    if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) < 0){ order[2].push(a[i]); }
}
```

Why do I get this error in the second **if** statement ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You get the error because `order[1]` is `undefined`.

That error message means that somewhere in your code, an attempt is being made to access a property with some name (here it's "push"), but instead of an object, the base for the reference is actually `undefined`.  Thus, to find the problem, you'd look for code that refers to that property name ("push"), and see what's to the left of it. In this case, the code is

```
if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) > 0){ order[1].push(a[i]); }
```

which means that the code expects `order[1]` to be an array. It is, however, *not* an array; it's `undefined`, so you get the error. Why is it `undefined`? Well, your code doesn't do anything to make it anything else, based on what's in your question.

Now, if you just want to place `a[i]` in a particular property of the object, then there's no need to call `.push()` at all:

```
var order = [], stack = [];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) == 0){ order[0] = a[i]; }
    if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) > 0){ order[1] = a[i]; }
    if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) < 0){ order[2] = a[i]; }
}
```

Comment: if it's defined as an object.. shouldn't i be able to use any number in there?

Comment: @d3nm4k no. You have to initialize `order[0]`, `order[1]`, and `order[2]` to have some value (an array I guess). That won't be done for you; why would it?

Comment: OH, got it! I would've spend a lot more hours just for getting order[1] = []; out. Thank You!

Comment: Thank you!!! No need to .push() at all, just assign.

Answer (score 80):

This error occurs in angular when you didn't intialise the array blank.
For an example:

```
userlist: any[ ];
this.userlist = [ ];
```

or

```
userlist: any = [ ];
```

Comment: If you want a safely typed array then, `public _userList: User[] = []`

Answer (score 30):

`order` is an `Object`, not an `Array()`.

`push()` is for arrays.

Refer [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925820/javascript-object-push-function)

Try this though(but your subobjects have to be `Arrays()`):

```
var order = new Array();

// initialize order; n = index
order[n] = new Array();

// and then you can perform push()
order[n].push(some_value);
```

Or you can just use order as an array of non-array objects:

```
var order = new Array();

order.push(a[n]);
```

Comment: Even if i define it as an array, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @d3nm4k do you just want to put the value of `a[i]` in either position 0, 1, or 2?  If so, you don't use `.push()` for that. The `.push()` method is for adding values to the **end** of an array.

Answer (score 17):

In most cases you have to initialize the array,

```
let list: number[] = [];
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed in the below way with typescript

1. Define and initialize firest

pageNumbers: number[] = [];

2. than populate it

   ```
   for (let i = 1; i < 201; i++) {
       this.pageNumbers.push(i);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Generally, Push method is used to add elements at the end of an array.

Here, you have used the push method to an object and not an array which is 'order'.

Steps to debug...

Change the object into an empty array,

```
var order = [], stack = [];
```

Now you can use the push method for this array as usual.

To use push method to this 'order' array; you should not use the array index when calling push method to an array. Just use the name of the array only.

```
var order = [], stack = [];

for(var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){

   if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) == 0){ 
     order.push(a[i]); 
   }

   if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) > 0){ 
     order.push(a[i]); 
   }

   if(parseInt(a[i].daysleft) < 0){ 
     order.push(a[i]); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to give an index.

Instead of doing `order[0].push(a[i])`, just do `order.push(a[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

answer to your question is simple order is not a object make it an array.
var order = new Array();
order.push(/*item to push*/);
when ever this error appears just check the left of which property the error is in this case it is push which is order[] so it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

order[] is undefined that's why

Just define order[1]...[n] to = some value

this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure add logical AND (&&) before.

```js
let users = [{id: 1, name: 'amoos'}, {id: 2, name: 'rifat'}]
let newUser = {id: 3, name: 'someone'} 
    users && users.push(newUser)    
    console.log('After', users)
```