# How to push to an array value in proxy object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

in normal object we can push to normal array value like obj.l =[]; obj.l.push("test")

Example.

```
var prxy =  new Proxy({} , {
get(target, name){
    return target[name]
}, 
set(target,name, value){
    target[name] = value; 
    return true;
}
})

prxy.h = {test : "test"}
>> {test: "test"}
prxy.h
>>{test: "test"}
prxy.h.push("test")
>>VM2724:1 Uncaught TypeError: prxy.h.push is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:8
```

Comment: `prxy.h` is not an Array, `push` is a method of Array.

Comment: push is a function of Array , but Proxy is an object

Comment: push() is for arrays, not objects, so use the right data structure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925820/javascript-object-push-function

Comment: what do you want returned?

Comment: @Durga — Arrays are objects too. The significance is that Proxy is not an array.

Comment: @Quentin , My bad, i never thought of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use array methods on an object. And there really wouldn't be a point here anyway. There's no reason to use `push()` when you can just append a value to an object:

```
prxy.h.someKey = someValue;
```

Or using a dynamic key:

```
var dynamicKey = "car";
prxy.h[dynamicKey] = someValue;
```