# json.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a command command that allows the author to set up a command for their server,
This is meant to update a json file not overwrite it,
I am using node.js and discord.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
module.exports = {
    name: 'setsuggest',
    execute(client, message, args, discord, cmd){
        const channelid = args[0]
        const serverid = message.guild.id
        
    
        fs.readFile('suggest.json', function (err, JsonData) {
            var json = JSON.parse(JsonData)
            let data = { 
                [serverid]: channelid 
            };
            json.push(data)
            fs.writeFile('suggest.json', JSON.stringify(json), function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('Updated')
            })
        })
        
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect json is an object not an array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925820/javascript-object-push-function

Answer (score 1):

If `json` is an object, as it seems from your usage, you could use the `spread` operator to populate a new object with all properties from the parsed object and the add the property from `serverid` to it:

```js
var json = {...JSON.parse(JsonData), [serverid]: channelid};
```

Otherwise you can always just assign the property in the parsed object directly:

```js
var json = JSON.parse(JsonData);
json[serverid] = channelid;
```