# How to avoid the "use the array literal notation" jslint error in the following javascript code

Tags: javascript, jslint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's wrong with var x = new Array();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885156/whats-wrong-with-var-x-new-array)

```
if (!Number.prototype.toZeroPaddedString) {
  Number.prototype.toZeroPaddedString = function (count) {
    "use strict";
    var str = this.toString();
    return (new Array(count + 1 - str.length)).join('0') + str;
  };
}
```

I want my code to be clean by jsLint standards, however, I just cannot imagine how to get rid of this error given what I want to do.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Not at all. How exactly do you plan to apply the answer to the question you mention in my case?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize the depth of this question.

Comment: And make sure you tidy your script with tabs or 4 spaces instead 2 spaces

Comment: I have defined it as 2, so I am good with that respect.

Comment: Elieder - that is a) personal preference and b) tabs suck on SO on  iDevices and 4 spaces is a waste of space on any mobile/tablet so I strongly disagree!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!Number.prototype.toZeroPaddedString) {
  Number.prototype.toZeroPaddedString = function (count) {
    "use strict";
    var str = this.toString();
    var ary = [];
    ary.length = count + 1 - str.length;
    return ary.join('0') + str;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The array literal notation is an alternative to using `new Array()` because Crockford (rightfully) doesn't like the `new` keyword. The notation is `[]`, just as the literal notation for `new Object()` is `{}`. To make it so that the length of the array is as desired, you can set `.length` on an array.

```
return (new Array(count + 1 - str.length)).join('0') + str;
```

To:

```
var arr = [];
arr.length = count + 1 - str.length;
return arr​.join('0') + str;
```

Comment: I may be dead wrong, but I believe `new Array(someNumber)` is different from `new Array(elem1, elem2, ...)` in that it creates an array of *length* `someNumber` with undefined elements.

Comment: `new Array(2) === [undefined, undefined]` whereas `[2]` is just `[2]`. Your answer seems to be simply misleading.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @delnan, I've updated my post, Mark.

Comment: Now that's what I call misuse of the comma operator. Why not split that up in separate statements? Also, you're missing a `var`, your version makes `arr` global.

Comment: @delnan I've updated again. Setting `var` wasn't working as I expected, so I set it as a global.