# Is there a difference between var i = []; and var i = new Array();

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering if there were a difference between:

```
var list = [];
```

and

```
var list = new Array();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885156/whats-wrong-with-var-x-new-array

Comment: I've seen answers that say `var list = new Array();` takes more horsepower to execute

Comment: @dandavis Actually they're not, but they're similar. Biggest danger is that `Array` doesn't need to be a "real" `Array`, while the literal syntax guarantees it. And at least in some scenarios is slower, although I doubt that really matters.

Comment: @DaveNewton: ok fine. as long as Array is native, they are the same. I would imagine that nearly always the case...