# JavaScript - for loop with an array

Tags: javascript, html

So here's what I've done so far:

```
<script>
text = new Array("t", "te", "tes", "test");
for(new i; i < text.length; i++)
{
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=text[i];
}
</script>


<body>
<span id='text'></span>
</body>
```

I'm going to add an timer later, but my question is, why do I get "ReferenceError 'i' is not defined"?
It is defined as you can see..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You declare a variable using `var` keyword. [JavaScript 101](http://hsablonniere.github.io/markleft/prezas/javascript-101.html).

Comment: Side note: you should generally use [array literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals) and not `new Array()`. In your case, that would look like `var text = ['t', 'te', 'tes', 'test'];`.

Comment: Matt, what does that matter? Just curious.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/931872/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1094723/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/885156/139010

Answer (score 7):

Instead of:

```
for(new i; i < text.length; i++)
```

Try this:

```
for(var i=0; i < text.length; i++)
```

You are using `new`, and in javascript we have to use `var` for declaring variables.

**Update1**

As @MattBall and @oxfn has mentioned in comments, your script is running before the `DOM` is ready. So you have to place the script after body tag.(or you can you [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)).

Following is working code:

```
<body>
    <span id='text'></span>
    <script>
    var text = new Array("t", "te", "tes", "test");
    for(var i=0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML +":"+ text[i];
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Didn't give me an error now, but it won't change the span's text to what's in the array? (as I don't have a timer right now, it goes to the end within a second, but shouldn't I see 'text' at least, in the span?)

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop your code is running before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Oh, right. I had this once before and just placed the jScript below, thanks, my bad.

Comment: @WoopWoopWoopWoop Place yor `<script>` at the end of `<body>`

Comment: Not "after body tag" but immediately before closing body tag.

Comment: Never ever select DOM nodes in loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this method aswell,

```
    var text = new Array("t", "te", "tes", "test");
    text.forEach(function(textvalue) {
        console.log(textvalue);
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=textvalue;
    });
```

**Ref:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

To display array content value into `<div id="text"></div>`

```
<script>
      function ArrayPrint(){
            var text = ["t", "te", "tes", "test"];
            text.forEach(function(textvalue) {
                console.log(textvalue);
                document.getElementById('text').innerHTML  += textvalue +' | ';
            });
      }
      window.onload = ArrayPrint;
</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<span id='text'></span>
</body>
</html>


<script  type="text/javascript">
text = new Array("t", "te", "tes", "test");
for(var i=0; i < text.length; i++)
{
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML=text[i];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As `int` in JavaScript is primitive type and it initialization not required the new keyword and JavaScript code working on DOM needs that DOM is already ready to use when code is running so place your script code at bottom just before close of body tag or call it on load.

Also you can cache length property it enhance performance.

```
    for(var i = 0,max=text.length; i < max; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML +":"+ text[i];
    }
```