# How can I access Java list elements from my client-side JavaScript code?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, el

I have the following simple script, which I am using to dynamically create the list elements in a `<ul>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generate(){
        var arr = new Array();
        <c:forEach items="${articles}" var="a" varStatus="status">
            $('#listitems').append(
                "<li>"+${a.title}+"</li>"
            );
            arr[${status.index}] ="${a.slideShow.images}";
        </c:forEach>
    }
</script>
```

My problem stems from the images attribute. Every article has a slideshow and every slideshow has a list of images. I want to pull out the very first image from the list of images via the jave list.get(index); I want to do something like **"${a.slideShow.images.get(0)}";**. The get() is a java method from the list object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Javascript is in no way related to Java, apart from the first four letters of the name.

Comment: Forget about Java, use plain (real javascript), and DOM (Document Object Model) to get the items in that UL. JavaScript is also typically client side code.

Comment: Guys, read the question and code instead of only title before commenting.

Comment: Titles are important.  Are they not a synopsis of the problem?  If the question states something different than the prose, might it not suggest a misunderstanding?

Comment: Hi guys,
I'm terrably sorry about the ambiguous wording. BalusC, point well taken. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In EL you can use the brace notation to access a `List` element by index. Thus, the following should do:

```
arr[${status.index}] = "${a.slideShow.images[0]}";
```

This will behind the scenes do exactly as you proposed: `a.getSlideShow().getImages().get(0)`.

That said, you normally declare JS arrays like follows:

```
var arr = [];
```

The `new` keyword is considered discouraged in JS.

Comment: new keyword discouraged for creating arrays?  Or always discouraged?

Comment: @Upper Stage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful

Comment: @Binaryrespawn: What do you mean with "causing my page not to load"? This is too ambiguous. If you get a blank page, check server logs for any exceptions/errors. If you get a normal page, but the images doesn't get loaded, rightclick page and view generated HTML/JS source code and verify if it is syntactically valid.

Comment: Hi,this stsatement did not work for me. It causes my page not to load, may be because there are articles with no slideshow and hence no images. Hence I did this, <c:if test="${a.slideShow.images != null}>arr[${status.index}] = ${a.slideShow.images[0]};</c:if> , but this causes my page not to load. and its the part where it said images[0]. Now the concept works, because, as a test, I tried ${articles[0].title} within the body and this worked. So I am really baffeled.

Comment: As said, just open page in browser and check generated JS code if it is **syntactically valid**. Maybe it represents a string value and you're forgotten singlequotes around the JS variable value.

Answer (score 1):

As those who commented on your question suggest, this is a common misunderstanding.  By the time your JavaScript executes (in the browser), Java and JSP and JSTL are no longer available.  The JSTL/JSP execute at the server to create source/HTML that is then sent to the client.

View source on your page - it might shed some light.  You should not see the JSP/JSTL you include above.

Comment: You are correct.  By the wording of the question and the attached comments, I was not certain he understood that.  Do you think my answer is confusing?