# Advantages of using [] over new Array() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What are the advantages of using

```
var foo = [];
```

over using

```
var bar = new Array();
```

i've been told to use [] over new Array() but never with much explanation

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The main reason to use `[]` as opposed to `new Array()` is the arguments you pass. When you use `new Array(10)`, you create an empty array with 10 elements, but when you use `[10]`, you create an array with one element who's value is `10`. Since this is generally the information most programmers want to pass to an array (as arrays are dynamic in Javascript), this is generally considered the best practice. Also `new Array(10,20)` works differently than `new Array(10)`. In this case you have the same effect as `[10,20]` which is to create an array with 2 elements, 10 and 20. Since this is... strange at best... it's easy to accidentally create an empty array by passing `new Array()` only one value. `[]` always has the same effect, so I'd also recommend sticking with it.

Comment: +1 I believe this is the main reason. If I recall correctly, the [] syntax was just not available in earlier JavaScript implementations.

Comment: Indeed, array and object literals were introduced in JavaScript 1.2. IE 4 and Netscape 4 both supported array and object literals, so both are entirely safe to use these days unless for some reason you need to cater for earlier versions of those browsers.

Comment: Another good reason to use [] is simply: `new Array()` => 11 characters; `[]` => 2 characters. Just use the short notation is both are pretty much equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

- shorter
- arguments of Array are confusing (e.g. `new Array(10)` and `new Array("10")` are quite different)

Comment: +1 Even worse: new Array(10) and new Array(10, 20) are completely different.

Answer (score 3):

Both can be used as good. This discussion/confusion has started since Javascript guru [Douglas Crockford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) told that [the `new` keyword is considered harmful](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/). Since then it was considered "good practice/technique" to leave out the `new` keyword to avoid unexpected results/behaviour. Also see this [Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful).

Comment: Also: jslint flags `new Array()` as a problem and suggests replacing it with `[]`.

Comment: The top answers at that link state that it is not harmful, and that there are many instances where it could be used. Furthermore, I see no danger or harm in "new Array()"

Comment: There are indeed no dangers if you use it consistently. It's just a "practice".

Comment: In this context I'm pretty sure they're synonyms in almost all engines.

Comment: "The new keyword is considered harmful." is no more useful than saying "use [] over new Array()". The question asked for explanations not rules.

I like the response "shorter and cleaner"

Comment: The potential harmfulness of `new` keyword as stated by Douglas Crockford is the origin of this all. I've edited the answer to include more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Three reasons (the first two expanded upon in other answers):

1. Shorter;
2. Allows creation of arrays with one element, as detailed in Chibu's answer;
3. Works even in the unlikely event of the `Array` constructor having been overwritten.

Non-reasons:

1. Avoidance of the `new` operator. Don't be afraid of `new` just because Douglas Crockford was once bitten by it. It's extremely useful.

Comment: I'll vote up anybody who says "Don't blindly listen to Douglas Crockford". He has great ideas, but he's not God and I particularly disagree with many of them

Answer (score 2):

It scores you less symbols in code golf.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing. The only reason to use `[]` over `new Array()` is that it's shorter.

Answer (score 1):

shorter and cleaner.  Should use {} to create objects as well.