# javascript error: invalid label? what does this mean?

Tags: javascript, multiple-browsers

**no worries! it looks like more text than it is ;-) so please go on reading!**

The Main Questions are:

- What does the error: **invalid label** mean?
- Where is the error in my script?

*now the geeky stuff begins ;-):*

I have a script which loads items of an language-array (items defined via lang_keys in js - see above) from the server (server delivers a JSON version of that array), for the current language.

with JS `translate("<synonym>");` function you get the required text in the current language. **UPDATE: jquery 1.5 not minified** (old: jquery.js (v1.4.1 - minified)) is loaded and lang.js too.

so I get an error, which I just can't find

I have to add: the `translate()` function works without errors and the JS is not interrupted. All functions work as desired.
**i don't have any other errors and all the JS works fine ... but i don't want to be surprised in the futur - so i need to get rid of that error.**

console output in chrome (which is listed after the ajax request [/query/js_lang/json]):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :    jQuery.jQuery.extend.globalEvaljquery.js:602
jQuery.ajaxSetup.converters.text            scriptjquery.js:6992
ajaxConvert                                 jquery.js:6884
done                                        jquery.js:6454
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback          jquery.js:7252
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send                   jquery.js:7261
jQuery.extend.ajax                          jquery.js:6646
(anonymous function)                        lang.js:116
```

console output in firefox (which is listed after the ajax request [/query/js_lang/json]):

```
invalid label
{"js_accept_terms":"Du musst unseren A...:"Kontaktname","js_agent_email":"Konta
```

***Can anyone tell me exactly what the error: `invalid label` means?***

My script (lang.js) looks like that:

```
var month_names = new Array();
var day_names = new Array();

var lang_keys = new Array(   
    "js_accept_terms",
    ...
    "nope"
);

var translations = new Array();


function translate(key, replace){
    var translated = translations[key];

    if(replace != undefined){
        for(var i=0; i<replace.length; i++){
            translated = translated.replace(/\%1/, replace); 
        }
    }

    return translated;
}

$.ajax({ //this is line 116
   url: "/query/js_lang/json",
   type: "post",
   data: {keys: JSON.stringify(lang_keys)},
   timeout: 7000,
   success: function(data){
       var trans = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
       for(var key in trans){
           translations[key.replace(/^js\_/, "")] = trans[key];
       }
       month_names = new Array(translate("jan"), translate("feb"), translate("mar"), translate("apr"), translate("may"), translate("jun"), translate("jul"), translate("aug"), translate("sep"), translate("oct"), translate("nov"), translate("dec"));
       day_names   = new Array(translate("sun"), translate("mon"), translate("tue"), translate("wed"), translate("thu"), translate("fri"), translate("sat"));
   },
   error: function(){
       out_message("Error. No Language loaded!", "Error");
   },
   async: false
});
```

`out_message()` displays a css-styled div. I am using that function in other parts of the website, where it works without any problems.

*I removed items in `lang_keys` where the return value has special characters like ':', umlauts, slashes and so on ... say: I tested it with only alphanumeric values and got the same error.*

*sorry for my English ;-) and thanks for your help*

Comment: {"js_accept_terms":"Du musst unseren A...:"Kontaktname", is invalid json. please escape the quotes with a slash

Comment: no .. in that case i would get the error, that my json is invalid. the json is parsed correctly, because the `translate()` function works

Comment: Don't use `new Array()`; Array literal syntax with `[]` is just better.

Comment: @missingno: thanks for the comment. may i ask why that's better?

Comment: [advantages-of-using-over-new-array-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517032/advantages-of-using-over-new-array-in-javascript)

Comment: i have changed that, but the error is still there. can anybody explain me the meaning of `invalid label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after some more research and some hints in StackOverflow threads i figured it out now:

The Problem is, that jQuery interpretes the ajax received data as a script (javascript) for some reason - must have something todo with `eval()` function, which interpretes the first json object as script because it looks like / starts like an object instance.

This occures (in my case) only if the **ajax call is done before the site is loaded completely**. well, with ajax calls inner some `$(function() { ... });` code there are no problems so far.

the trick was to add brakets around the json string in the php script

`$return_value = "(" . json_encode($translation) . ")";`

and remove them after receiving in the ajax-success callback

```
$.ajax({    
    ...,
    success: function(data){
           data = data.substring(1,data.length-1); // for label error reason. getting json in breaktes,, which must be removed again
           var trans = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          ...
```

just fyi about labels: [here some information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Label) about that

Comment: for better readability - there is some paradigm which suggest the code shell be written in a way where you use less comments - you could remove the brackets via a regular expression...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the returned JSON:

```
{"js_accept_terms":"Du musst unseren A...:"Kontaktname","js_agent_email":"Konta
```

This should look something like this:

```
{"js_accept_terms":"Du musst unseren A...:\"Kontaktname","js_agent_email":"Konta
```

There may be a problem on the server side. Your JSON encoder does not escape double quotes.

Comment: no thats the how firebug displays json. it is escaped and unicode encoded.