# Size of undefined and null

Tags: javascript, variables

May I ask a size of undefined or null on a variable, which is bigger in javascript??

```
a = undefined

b = null

a > b ? undefined is bigger : null is bigger
```

Comment: which language? static compiled or dynamic run?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont very understand your question. I want to know the size in js

Comment: Check this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499352/does-null-occupy-memory-in-javascript)

Comment: It has no sense ask for the size of undefined or null variable... what is your point?

Comment: @MiguelMatos : he asked which one is bigger, not what is the bigger memory footprint of the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Types are [incomparable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability). Thus, neither a nor b is the biggest:

```
> var a = undefined
undefined
> a
undefined
> var b = null
undefined
> b
null
> a > b
false
> b > a
false
```

(source: Developer Tools' console)

edit: if you're asking about the memory footprint, it depends on the implementation of the Javascript Engine you're using.