# Undefined Vs Null (In terms of memory allocation) for example in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Looking the code-snippet:

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
var d;
a = undefined;
b = null;
d = 15;
d = undefined;
```

Now, I want to know the memory allocation (in terms of heap, stack or whatever) while writing this code.

For variables a, b, c, d -- what is the size of memory allocation? or in what order? 
also, is there any memory allocation for a, c, d? 
also, if we are setting value undefined for a or d -- what does it mean? does it mean that memory allocation is to be done and 'undefined' to be stored in it? or for d -- release 'memory-allocation' and do nothing?

Very confused. Anybody ... have some idea?

> **Note:** Already seen
>
> - [Does null occupy memory in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499352/does-null-occupy-memory-in-javascript)
> - [Javascript memory impact of null vs undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854916/javascript-memory-impact-of-null-vs-undefined)

kindly don't mark duplicate.

Comment: The ECMAScript specification doesn’t contain such implementation details. As far it is concerned there is just “memory” and `null` and `undefined` are values like any other. If you wonder how a specific implementation does it, then you should include which one. According to the spec, all variables are created and initialized with `undefined`.

Comment: Your titular question seems to be an exact duplicate of the second one you found. How did it not answer your question?

Comment: "*also, is there any memory allocation for a, c, d?*" - why are you excluding `b` here, do you think `null` is somehow special?

Comment: All the values in your question are primitives, and won't be allocated as a separate object on the heap. There is no memory allocation and deallocation other than for the `var` declaration itself.