# javascript setInterval in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval

I created an array and inserted a setInterval in it, but `tmp[0]` doesn't work

```
tmp = new Array();
v = new Array();
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
j = 0;
tmp[i] = setInterval("if(j<10+(i*5)){alert(i+' '+j);j++;}else{clearInterval(tmp[i])}", 1000);
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: It should alert: "0 0" "1 0" "0 1" "1 1" "0 2" "1 2" ...

Comment: @キューゾ リファイ see the update to my answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do Not** use eval. Try this:

```
var tmp = new Array();
var v = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var j = 0;
    tmp[i] = setInterval(function () {
        if (j < 10 + (i * 5)) {
            alert(i + ' ' + j);
            j++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(tmp[i])
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FKEL6/  (it is annoying with the popups, just so you are aware.)

---

This might do what you want it to do:

```
var tmp = new Array();
var v = new Array();
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    createTmp(i);
}

function createTmp(p){
    var j = 0;
    tmp[p] = setInterval(function () {
        if (j < 10 + (p * 5)) {
            alert(p + ' ' + j);
            j++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(tmp[p])
        }
    }, 1000);
}
console.log(tmp);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FKEL6/5/ (also has annoying alerts)

Comment: OP isn't using eval, they're using the deprecated form of `setInterval` by passing a string.

Comment: @キューゾ リファイ what does that mean `it doesnt run`? what do you want it to do?

Comment: Using a function creates another problem: scope.

Comment: @キューゾ リファイ i will always be 2 because it is a global variable... and you increased it in the loop.

Comment: @キューゾ リファイ I believe this might do what you want it to do: http://jsfiddle.net/FKEL6/5/

Comment: Why are you using `new Array();` instead of `[]`? Shouldn't you should show a novice the best practices, if any?

Comment: @David -- why do you assume that *that* is the `best practice`?

Comment: @David -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517032/advantages-of-using-over-new-array-in-javascript there is **no** difference when it is empty...

Answer (score 0):

The output of such a thing is:

```
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
...
2 18
2 19
```

etc, which is correct. It stops when j < 20.

But at the end your timer is still going on and all you are doing is calling clearInterval(tmp[2]) over and over, twice a second.