# difference between Function and new Function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, new-operator

I sometimes see people doing this `Function('alert("hi")')` and sometimes they do `new Function('alert("hi")')`

Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Except under rare circumstances, you shouldn't do either.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful

Comment: They're similar in that they're instances of `DoingItWrong` (implied `eval` where `function() { alert("hi"); }` works just as well? WTF, people).

Comment: Don't use Function constructors with arguments. Please.

Comment: @Raynos When should it be used then?

Comment: @user: Under extremely rare circumstances.  If you have to ask, just don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.1.1) (page 127) says they're identical.

> ### 15.3.1.1 Function (p1, p2, … , pn, body)
>
> When the `Function` function is called
>   with some arguments p1, p2, … , pn,
>   body (where n might be 0, that is,
>   there are no “p” arguments, and where
>   body might also not be provided), the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Create and return a new Function object as if the standard built-in
>      constructor Function was used in a new
>      expression with the same arguments
>      (15.3.2.1).

---

However, you should avoid the `Function` constructor at all costs.
It needs to `eval` the string you pass to it; `eval` is evil, and slow too.

Comment: Ahh! Please sector / page number with a link to the spec.

Comment: @SLaks it's their fault for not having #15.3 to prepend to the url.

Comment: @Raynos: It's a PDF.  They couldn't do that if they tried (AFAIK)

Comment: @SLaks: You're welcome. @CMS referenced it in a comment just the other day.

Comment: @Raynos: Sadly, that's the extent of my powers. Referencing someone else's hard work. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one usage of `new Function`. It is this:

```
var constructor = new Function;

// then this 

constructor.prototype = { 
    //...  stuff
};

// OR

constructor.prototype = new someOtherThing;

// then

var obj = new constructor;
```

Basically you can use `new Function` if you want to create an object constructor with an empty constructor that only uses inheritance.

If you want a function to do anything then don't use `Function` at all.

Comment: How is that better than `function(){}`?

Comment: @SLaks it's a matter of style. But it's still the only valid usage of `new Function`

Comment: Believe it or not, jQuery uses `new Function(...)`.

Comment: @SLaks That's just using eval without using eval. Is there any argument for new Function vs eval ?

Comment: @Raynos, I would say the ´Function´ constructor is safer than ´eval´, because it uses a completely new variable/lexical environment (you have access only to identifiers declared in the global scope, or within the function itself, and not to the scope of the caller).

Comment: @CMS: Yeah, after realizing that, I noted it, then decided to delete. My example was embarrassingly flawed. :o)

Comment: @CMS that prints overwritten by Function for me in chrome. It's a poor example of what your trying to show

Comment: Raynos: That's completely my fault. He was pointing out the terrible flaw in my example, which I deleted. Sorry for the confusion. I think [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/GJXAk/1/) illustrates what @CMS is saying.

Comment: @patrickdw that example is safe anyway because of invoking `new` on that function creates a unique `this` scope. This illustrates it more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/GJXAk/4/. @CMS Thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: Raynos: My example made the same mistake as the first, in that it didn't execute the function. Ugh! This would be the correct one. http://jsfiddle.net/GJXAk/5/

Comment: Raynos: I think I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: `Function(...)` and `new Function(...)` are exactly the same according to the [ECMA5 specs](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.1.1).

To shed some light as to when and where this should be used, the answer is rarely. I know of one situation where we have used `Function(...)`, and it was when creating custom ASP.NET server controls. We often have something to the effect of `[ServerControl].OnClientClick`, which specifies a JavaScript string (on the server side) that should be ran on the client side when the click event occurs. We then put the JS string into a Function and call it when specific conditions have been met. This also allows us to invoke the `.call(...)` function to set the context and to pass in the event parameters as if the JS were being called from an `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking the Function constructor as a function (without using `new` operator) has the same same effect as invoking it as constructor.

That means it is same to code if you do it:

```
var result1 = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b')
var result2 = Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b')
```

result1 and result2 are same.