# Are the following statements in javascript equivalent?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a reason not to use `new Object()` in JavasScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194220/is-there-a-reason-not-to-use-new-object-in-javasscript)
>   [Create an empty object in JavaScript with {} or new Object()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251402/create-an-empty-object-in-javascript-with-or-new-object)

In javascript, are the following two statements equivalent?

```
var c = new Object();

var c = {};
```

Comment: Yes! Though, the latter is preferred.

Comment: warning `new Array()` and `[]` are not the same

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez: How are they different? If you're referring to the argument list of `Array()`'s constructor, that's not relevant.

Comment: Yeah I was referring to the args. It's a difference and it's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From §11.1.5 Object Initialiser:

> The production ObjectLiteral : { } is evaluated as follows:
>
> Return a new object created as if by the expression new Object() where Object is the standard built-in constructor with that name.

Comment: You knew this was an exact dup, why did you answer it?