# Simple way to use variables in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This almost has the answer...
[How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

I need to know if I can use variables instead of hardcode in the regex?

```
str1 = str1.replace(/abcdef/g, "stuvwxyz");
```

can I use variables instead of /abcdef/g and "stuvwxyz"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course that you can, every single bit of this can be dynamic:

```
var pattern = 'abcdef';
var input = 'stuvwxyz';
var modifiers = 'g';
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, modifiers);
var str1 = 'Hello abcdef';
str1 = str1.replace(regex, input);
```

Checkout the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as well.

Comment: Is there any reason to use new here?

Comment: @kennebec, you may checkout the following thread about the `new` keyword in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful

Comment: These answers are all just about the same (or were, you did some fast editing) but you were first.

Comment: Other answers don't mention how to make the regex dynamic, just the string to be searched and the what to replace it with.

Comment: @juan-mendes yes juan... that is why I said "or were" he edited really fast... he is good. His initial answer was just like the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
var pattern = /abcdef/g;
var input = "stuvwxyz";
str1 = str1.replace(pattern, input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var regex = /abcdef/g;
var string = "stuvwxyz";
var str1 = "abcdef";
str1 = str1.replace(regex, string);
```