# Strict mode alternatives to this instanceof arguments.callee

Tags: javascript, constructor, arguments, strict-mode

There's an old trick ([that I learned on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/)) to catch calling a constructor as a function, i.e. forgetting the `new` keyword. The following, or something like, it goes in each constructor at the top.

```
if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
    throw Error("Constructor called as a function");
}
```

What are the alternatives when you need to `"use strict";` ?

Can its generic nature be retained? Or do we have to use the name of the constructor in place of `arguments.callee`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arguments.callee` itself is deprecated in favor of named function expressions.  Although I don't necessarily agree with this move, it is how things have progressed.  As such, replacing `arguments.callee` with the function name is the only way in strict mode, and is also the preferred way in non-strict mode.