# getting this error " $.toJSON is not a function "

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to use jQuery and Ajax and I use this method. but I get the error $.toJSON is not a function in my firebug . where is the problem? I use jquery 1.3.2 . thanks

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#S1").click(function 
            () {
            $("#t1").slideToggle("fast");
            $("#S1").css("background-color", "yellow");
            var ID = $("#HiddenField2").attr("Value");
            var params = new Object();
            params.Key = ID;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen",
                data: $.toJSON(params),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's correct.

There is no `$.toJSON()` function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.toJSON. Perhaps you want to use [`JSON.stringify()`](http://www.json.org/js.html) instead.

Comment: +1. No reason to use an extra library when it's built into all modern browsers.

Comment: btw not all browsers have the json library built into it.. You need to include json2.js in that case..

Comment: If there's no such method, [what is this guy using in his code](http://benjamin-schweizer.de/jquerypostjson.html)?!

Comment: @SNag that blog post is 6 years old, but let's ignore that fact... did you see the comment in there that says _"Below is an proposed update. As it relies on your json plugin, you to add it to your code base so that other jQuery users can of it"_ ? It's not real code. It's a proposal.

Comment: @MattBall: That proposal is for the inclusion of `$.postJSON` as a function (since we have `$.get`, `$.getJSON`,`$.post` but no `$.postJSON`). He makes no mention of inclusion of `$.toJSON`! Oh well, I guess the whole of it must be a proposal!

Comment: Worked for me as well... Thanks Matt 

Comment: JSON.stringify() link is broken

Comment: do you guys aware that JSON.stringify put $id to the end of each object which makes circle referenced metainfo marked-up JSON string to be unusable and totally compatible with .NET?

Answer (score 10):

You need to include the `jquery-json` library from http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ on your page.

Answer (score 9):

I'm learning jquery and I have the same problem.
My mistake -  in this line of code which interrupted me:

```
var params = $.toJSON(request);
```

After replacing it with this code:

```
var params = JSON.stringify(request);
```

I did not get any error.

But please help me know how you want your method `readen`  :

url: "viewMessages.aspx/readen"

Comment: how would i change `[].toJSON()`

Answer (score 3):

You are already included jquery, there is no reason to use any other library, just use $.parseJSON(a_json_string) :

```
var error_json_string = '{"error":{"message":"message blablabla","type":"","code":""}}';
var error_json_obj = $.parseJSON(error_json_string);

alert(error_json_obj.error.message);
```

Source :
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Seems worth pointing out that the OP stated that they were using jQuery 1.3.2, and `.parseJSON()` was added in 1.4.1.

Comment: Yes, it's available from 1.4.1, i am working with the last version http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js, i think it's no problem when upgrade to it!, depend of the situation (should try) :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
data: params,
```

OR

```
var params = {key:ID},
```

Comment: it's not working, I get this  "Invalid JSON primitive: Key." and There are no child objects

Comment: first of all remove this contentType: "application/json", line try with var param  = {'key':ID},