# AJAX in jsFiddle

Tags: ajax, jquery, same-origin-policy, jsfiddle

How do you simulate jQuery [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to load data from a different domain in jsFiddle?

```
/* This won't work in jsFiddle. */    
$.get("http://www.google.com", function(data) { ... } );
```

As we know, there is limitation:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by creating a Fiddle in jsFiddle just for testing Ajax loads. It’s some very simple HTML with an image and some copy — you can see it here:

```html
<div class="container">
    <img id="picture" src="http://media.smashingmagazine.com/uploads/2012/01/best-of-no-150px.png" />

    <p>This post will help you get to know the iOS SDK a little better. It leads you through some choreographed steps of iOS app development, even if you have little or no programming knowledge. It covers some key principles and applies these directly to something useful and relevant: the creation of a simple but functioning portfolio app for the iPhone.</p>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #333333;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

img {
    margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;   
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        border-radius: 8px;

}

.container {
  background: #fafafa;  
  padding: 1em;        
}
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deborah/pkmvD/).

If you use Firebug to click on the “result” frame, you can get the source URL of the iframe. When you copy this source URL into the Fiddle containing your Ajax request, it will work because now it is on the same domain. Here’s a demonstration:

```html
<div class="excontainer">
    <button id="loadbasic">basic load</button>
    <div id="result"></div>

</div>
```

```css
body {
 font-family: Arial;   
}

.excontainer {
  padding: 1em;    
}

label {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;   
}

p {
 padding: .5em;   
}

a, a:visited {
 color: #2d9afd;   
}

.changed {
  color: #ff0099;   
}

.highlight {
  background: #faffda;   
}

.entered {
  color: #f5560a;
}

.green {
 color: #7fbf38;   
}

.hellomouse, .clickable, #foo, #event {
 cursor: pointer;   
}

button {
 margin-bottom: 1em;   
}

div {
  margin: 1em 0;   
}

#foo {
 display: inline-block;   
}



ul {
 margin: 1em 0;   
}

.form, form, .stuff, .morestuff, stuff3 {
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #ececec;
}

input {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 padding: 2px;    
}

.placeholder {
   color: #ff0099;  
   font-weight: normal; 
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #cccccc;
}

:-moz-placeholder {  
   color: #cccccc;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #cccccc;
}

:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color:transparent;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #eeeeee;     
}
```

```js
// learn jquery ajax 
// http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

// no need to specify document ready

$(function(){
    // don't cache ajax or content won't be fresh
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<img src='http://automobiles.honda.com/images/current-offers/small-loading.gif' alt='loading...' />";

    // load() functions
    var loadUrl = "http://fiddle.jshell.net/deborah/pkmvD/show/";
    $("#loadbasic").click(function(){
        $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
    });

// end  
});
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deborah/Ln95K/31/).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [How can I use the JSFiddle echo feature with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194408/how-can-i-use-the-jsfiddle-echo-feature-with-jquery).

Also check out their [API](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) which gives examples to how achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This simple example should do, try out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thewiseguy99/BWA9D/).

You need to create a JSON object wrapping your actual data in a *json* element.

```
var callEcho = function(json) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        type: "POST",
        data: json
    }).done(function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    });
};

$.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two", function(data) {
    var json = {
       json: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    callEcho(json);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to do some examples you can use JSONP and the twitter api for testing purposes. If your server supports JSON requests, then i don't think that there should be any problem.

Just set the data type as JSON as shown below

---

```
$.ajax("http://search.twitter.com/search.json", {
    data: {
        q: 'jquery'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

Does this help?

Comment: $.get() will work just fine. I am just too used to making use of the ajax function.

Comment: He is asking for JSFiddle. JSFiddle will not allow this.

Comment: @jostster Do you mean to say that jsfiddle does not allow the twitter url that i mentioned?