# Add jquery datatables table footer via Javascript without using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I define my jquery datatables without any HTML besides the base table element. This is my HTML:

```
<table id="mytable"></table>
```

Then I do all the table configuration via the datatables definition. Example code:

```
var dataSet = [
    {name: "storage101", size: 492},
    {name: "storage102", size: 742},
    {name: "storage103", size: 423}
]

$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    sDom: '<"top"i>rCt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
});

$("#storages").dataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    aoColumns: [
        {title: "Name", mData: "name"},
        {title: "Size", mData: "size"}
    ],
    oLanguage: {sEmptyTable: "No logs"},
    fnFooterCallback: function(nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
        var api = this.api();
        var size = 0;
        aaData.forEach(function(x) {
            size += (x['size']);
        });
        // I need a footer in my table before doing this, what is the smartest way to add the footer?
        $(api.column(1).footer()).html(
            size
        );        
    }
});
```

Now I would like to use the footer callback to show sums of my dataset inside the footer.

Unfortunately, adding HTML to the footer (like in this example: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) does not work as the table does not contain any tfoot element and the required row and columns.
What would be a clean way to add footer for all my columns?

JSFiddle with the code above:
http://jsfiddle.net/36twp251/1/

Comment: Could you add further code/information to your question to allow us to recreate your problem? And, if possible, fork this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8566wmap/) to recreate an approximation of your use-case? AJAX can be included using JS Fiddle's "[echo](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)" API, with some clarification in another SO question "[AJAX in jsFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045274/ajax-in-jsfiddle)."

Comment: @DavidThomas sure, I changed the fiddle accordingly, should some up the problem well enough!

Comment: You won't be able to add footer with DataTables without `<tfoot>` element. So are you asking how to do it without modifying HTML? I assuming you have no control over HTML, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers say I need to define the footer beforehands somehow. Not perfect, but at least I can keep my HTML clean (just defining table and its id but nothing more):

```
// globally defined table to be reused in several views
$.fn.storageTable = function() {
    $(this).append("<tfoot><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></tfoot>")
    return this.dataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        aoColumns: [
            {title: "Name", mData: "name"},
            {title: "Size", mData: "size"}
        ],
        oLanguage: {sEmptyTable: "No logs"},
        fnFooterCallback: function(nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
            var api = this.api();
            var size = 0;
            aaData.forEach(function(x) {
                size += (x['size']);
            });
            $(api.column(1).footer()).html(size);       
        }
    });
}

// sample usage
$("table-storages").storageTable();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ifischer/Ljwgrkq0/3/

Answer (score 11):

#### CAUSE

It's not possible to manipulate footer without presence of `<tfoot>` element.

#### SOLUTION #1

Add appropriate markup as described  in [DataTables - Installation](http://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML).

#### SOLUTION #2

If you don't have access to HTML, see alternative solutions below.

- **Using `dom`**

  You can use [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) to create a `<div class="footer"></div>` and add content there, for example:

  ```js
  $("#storages").dataTable({
     dom: '<"top"i>rCt<"footer"><"bottom"flp><"clear">',
     columns: [
        {title: "Name", data: "name"},
        {title: "Size", data: "size"}
     ],
     fnFooterCallback: function(nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
        var api = this.api();
        var size = 0;
        aaData.forEach(function(x) {
              size += (x['size']);
        });
        $('.footer').html(size);
     }
  });
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36twp251/3/) for demonstration.
- **Adding `<tfoot>`**

  You can add `<tfoot>` element with JavaScript **before** initializing DataTables, then your original code would work without problems.

  However you need to insert correct number of `<th></th>` elements for each table.

  ```js
  $("#storages").append('<tfoot><tr><th></th><th></th></tr></tfoot>');
  ```

  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36twp251/4/) for demonstration.

Comment: after i add (append the tfoot)  the footer row to table via javascript, the DataTable column no longer extend (nowrap) and they show fixed width and data in them wraps....

Answer (score 2):

One means of doing this is the following – though I can't necessarily claim it to be 'the smartest':

```
fnFooterCallback: function (nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay) {
    // getting a reference to the <table> itself (as a jQuery object):
    var table = this;
    var api = table.api();
    var size = 0;
    aaData.forEach(function (x) {
        size += (x['size']);
    });

    // finding the number of cells in the row with the largest
    // number of cells (for later use as a colspan attribute,
    // assuming that you want only one cell in the <tr> of the
    // footer).
    // first finding all <tr> elements within the <table>,
    // using get() to convert that collection to an array:
    var maxColumnLength = table.find('tr').get()
    // using Array.prototype.reduce() to compare
    // the length (size) of each row's cells collection:
                          .reduce(function (a, b) {
    // keeping the current <tr> (a) if its cells.length
    // is larger than the currently-assessed <tr> (b):
                              return a.cells.length > b.cells.length;
    // finding the number of cells contained in the
    // <tr> that has the largest collection of cells:
                          }).cells.length;

    // setting the tfoot variable to *either* the current
    // <tfoot> element (if one might exist from being
    // previously created), or creating
    // a <tfoot> if one does not already exist:
    var tfoot = this.find('tfoot').length ? this.find('tfoot') : $('<tfoot>', {
    // setting the innerHTML of the created-<tfoot>:
        'html': '<tr><td class="result" colspan="' + size + '"></td></tr>'
    // inserting it before the first <tbody> element:
    }).insertBefore($(this).find('tbody'));

    // finding the <td> element with the class of 'result'
    // (obviously adjust to taste), and setting its text:
    tfoot.find('td.result').text(size);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/36twp251/2/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
  - [`HTMLTableRowElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement).
- jQuery:

  - [Creating elements with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).