# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'set' on backbone-min.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am receiving this error message when including backbone in my application,

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'set'

but I have jquery (1.4.4) and underscore.js (1.1.7) loaded before backbone, why is this method still missing?

Comment: there might be a clash between the javascript libraries, try using the `noConflict`

Comment: Does backbone.js work with that older version of jQuery? I've never tried. No conflict doesn't have anything to do with this issue unless there is another library being included other than jQuery. underscore.js does not conflict with jQuery.

Comment: On which line of which code does this error occur? Could you post some code please??

Answer (score 5):

Or you are instantiating a model without `new` prefix which would cause it to be bound to global window instead of `this`. [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383423/327317).

Answer (score 1):

Based solely on the error message, I would search your code for `this.set`. It appears that you're referencing `this`with the expectation that it's a model, but the function isn't bound correctly.