# Why does Crockford say not to use the new keyword if he advises us to use it for prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript

I saw a video in which Crockford told us not to use the `new` keyword. He said to use Object.create instead if I'm not mistaken. Why does he tell us not to use `new` if he has used it in achieving prototypal inheritance in this article that he wrote: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html

I would expect him to use Object.create instead of `new`, like this:

```
function object(o) {
    return Object.create((function() {}).prototype = o);
}
```

So why is it that he still uses `new`?

Comment: Maybe he learned something since that video/article? It's hard to know without the video/context.

Comment: Probably a combination of A) `Object.create` not being [supported](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) across a handful of browsers, and B) that article having been written several years ago; his programming style, like most of ours, has probably changed and evolved since then.

Comment: Here's the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook (I don't know exactly where in the video he said that, sorry)

Comment: Also, in the article you reference, his addendum on 2008-04-07 essentially answers this, where he defines `Object.create` if it doesn't exist. You'd only have to use `new` that one time (defining `Object.create`).

Comment: Is that your code in the question, or did you find it somewhere? The reason I ask is that the `(function() {}).prototype = ` part of it has no effect on your code. You'll get the same result if you do `return Object.create( o );`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript 's "new" Keyword Considered Harmful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful)

Comment: As of November 2017, Douglas Crockford says he has stopped using `new`, `Object.create()`, _and_ `this`: https://youtu.be/DxnYQRuLX7Q?t=29m6s

Comment: @ESV Wow so much has changed since 2011. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crockford discusses `new` and `Object.create` in [this Nov 2008 message to the JSLint.com mailing list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/314).  An excerpt:

> If you call a constructor function without the `new` prefix, instead of
>   creating and initializing a new object, you will be damaging the
>   global object. There is no compile time warning and no runtime
>   warning. This is one of the language’s bad parts.
>
> In my practice, I completely avoid use of `new`.

Comment: Maybe I am not familiar with all javascript hacks, but why would anyone call a constructor function without the `new` keyword?!?

Comment: What Crockford *actually* says is that if you *omit* the new keyword you will clobber the global object. It is the risk of omitting it which is the reason why he recommend not to use it. It is required for constructor objects.

Answer (score 5):

This is a really old question, but…

When Crockford wrote [the article you mention](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) and [the discussion linked by Paul Beusterien](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/314), there was no [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It was 2008 and `Object.create` was, at most, a proposal (or really rarely implemented in browsers).

His final formulation is basically a polyfill:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}

newObject = Object.create(oldObject);
```

His only use of `new` is, therefore, to simulate (or emulate) what `Object.create` must do.

He doesn’t advise us to use it. He presents a polyfill that uses it, so you don’t have to use it anywhere else.