# Calling Javascript Factory Method

Tags: javascript

I am learning Object Oriented Java Script. I have below code for Factory Method.

```
function Foo() {
    var value = 1;
    return {
        method: function() {
            return value;
        },
        value:value
    }
}
Foo.prototype = {
    bar: function() {}
};

new Foo();
Foo();
```

method Foo can be called by two ways. `new Foo();` or `Foo();` Both do the same thing and output is same. what is actual difference in java script processing ?

Comment: Note that setting `Foo.prototype = {something}` is pointless if you are going to return your own object from the `Foo()` function rather than going with the object that JS creates for you when you say `new Foo()`.

Comment: @Bakudan - JavaScript is object-oriented by any reasonable definition of the term.

Comment: @Bakudan, If you have something to say(Object Oriented vs Object Based), justify it with example in new Answer. It will help newbies :)

Comment: @onemach, you can contribute in answer, rather than spelling error :)

Comment: Not worthy of its own answer probably, but notice that `new Foo` won't have a property `bar`. When using `new`, if you don't return an object, `Foo.prototype` is returned. Since you're creating an object literal in each invocation, it is returned instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal cases, `new` should be used when creating objects from a constructor function and eschewed when performing any other function call. When using `new` on a function 1) a new object is created; 2) the function is called with the value of `this` bound to that new object, and 3) the value returned from the function (by default) is the object created in step one.

However, in your case you're returning a completely new object from the "constructor" (different from the object in 1) above), which means there is no practical difference. The value of `this` will still be different inside the function, but both of these will return `false`:

```
new Foo() instanceof Foo;
Foo() instanceof Foo;
```

To illustrate the `this` difference, add the following to `Foo`:

```
alert(this instanceof Foo)
```

When called with `new` this alerts `true`; when called without it, `false`.

Furthermore, there's no point in assigning an object to `Foo.prototype` because you'll never create any instances of `Foo` that would make use of it (because, again, you're returning something completely different from `Foo`).

If you're going to return a custom object from `Foo` then you should prefer the version without `new`; there's no point in creating a new instance of `Foo` if you're going to ignore it and return something completely different, anyway.

Comment: Yes. I tested both returns false. Any little example of "The value of this will be different inside the function" ?

Comment: Its better explanation. new creates the instance of Foo, whereas without new keeps just a static Object, that can be used anytime. correct ?

Comment: Further, setting `Foo.prototype` becomes pointless since the objects you create are not instances of `Foo`.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Yeah, I was just thinking about making a similar comment. I think I'll update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great link:

[Is Javascript "new" considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful)

See also:

http://phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Javascript_Pitfalls.html

But here's the best link (and, really, the answer to your question:

> http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html
>
> JavaScript is a class-free, object-oriented language, and as such, it
>   uses prototypal inheritance instead of classical inheritance. This can
>   be puzzling to programmers trained in conventional object-oriented
>   languages like C++ and Java...

Answer (score 1):

The javascript new keyword in functions is pretty weird. The best (only?) in depth explanation of what is happening I've been able to find is actually [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/5056) from Daniel Howard.

Should be required reading for anyone trying to learn some of the more advanced concepts of Javavscript.

By the way, you can get **really** far in js by never using the new keyword at all. Notice how basically none of the code using jquery relies on it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning an object from `Foo`, the use of `new` has no effect. The return values of `Foo()` and `new Foo()` will **not** be instances of `Foo`; instead, they'll be instances of the type of whatever value  you returned.

This same behavior is seen if you return any† object or any function from your constructor. **However**, if `Foo` were to return:

- A string
- A number
- `null`
- `undefined` (same as returning nothing at all)
- or `this`

...then the return value of `new Foo()` **would** be an instance of `Foo`.

You can test out the code below on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdleyEskridge/Z3U2X/):

```
function ReturnsString() { return "string"; }
function ReturnsNumber() { return 1; }
function ReturnsNull() { return null; }
function ReturnsUndefined() { return void 0; }
function ReturnsThis() { return this; }
function ReturnsFunction() { return function() {}; }
function ReturnsObject() { return {}; }

alert("Results:"
    + "\nReturnsString: " + (new ReturnsString() instanceof ReturnsString)
    + "\nReturnsNumber: " + (new ReturnsNumber() instanceof ReturnsNumber)
    + "\nReturnsNull: " + (new ReturnsNull() instanceof ReturnsNull)
    + "\nReturnsUndefined: " + (new ReturnsUndefined() instanceof ReturnsUndefined)
    + "\nReturnsThis: " + (new ReturnsThis() instanceof ReturnsThis)
    + "\nReturnsFunction: " + (new ReturnsFunction() instanceof ReturnsFunction)
    + "\nReturnsObject: " + (new ReturnsObject() instanceof ReturnsObject)
);
```

The `ReturnsFunction` and `ReturnsObject` constructors will both show a `false` result, meaning they don't return an `instanceof` themselves when used with the `new` operator.

All of the other constructors **do** return an `instanceof` themselves when used with the `new` operator.

† Except `this`, as I mentioned above

Comment: You mean, functions & objects don't return instance of itself. So Foo() and new Foo() also doesn't. but, if they return something else. They are part of their own instance !

Comment: @Umesh, that's exactly right. I find this behavior to be pretty unintuitive! Thank goodness for [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/). ;)