# What is the difference between these arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var foo = {}
var bar = new Array();
var another = [];
```

Also, is it possible to add to `foo` like so:

```
foo['obj'] = new Date();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> var foo = {};
> ```

`foo` is an object literal.

> ```
> var bar = new Array();
> ```

`bar` is an array initialized via the `Array` constructor.

> ```
> var another = [];
> ```

`another` is an array literal. Creating new arrays through literals is more efficient than doing so through the `Array` constructor: http://jsperf.com/new-array And it’s also much easier to type ;) I’d recommend using array literals wherever possible.

> Also, is it possible to add in foo like so: `foo['obj'] = new Date();`

Yes. That will add a property `obj` to `foo` with the value of `new Date()`. It’s [equivalent](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties) to `foo.obj = new Date();`.

Comment: @SeanDokko Glad to hear I could help. Please click the √ mark next to my answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is an object, not an array.
`bar` and `another` are arrays.

if you give `foo['obj'] = new Date();`, `obj` will become a property of foo.

Answer (score 0):

> var foo = {}

This is an object, not an array.

> var bar = new Array();

This is array [but avoid `new` keyword with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful).

> var another = [];

This is correct way of initializing array.

> Also, is it possible to add in foo like so: foo['obj'] = new Date();

There is no associative array in JS. You can instead do:

```
var foo = {};
var foo['obj'] = new Date();
```

Comment: “There is no associative array in JS.” No, but you can add key-value pairs to arrays: `var array = []; array.foo = 42; console.log(array, array.foo); // logs [] and then 42`.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: That's true but this clears the confusion most devs have with it :)

Answer (score 0):

**bar** and **another** are the same, but:

```
var foo = {};
```

foo is not an array rather an object

```
foo['obj'] = new Date(); //same as
foo.obj = new Date();
```

the advantage of **f['obj']** is that you can use non-valid identifier characters ex:

```
   foo['test-me'] // is valid
   foo.test-me //not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = {} is for object referal,
    foo = {myCar: "Saturn", getCar: CarTypes("Honda"), special: Sales}
```

while 
    `var bar = new Array();` is used to create new empty array.

But `var another = [];` can be used to assign any array empty values as well as creates empty array.
I think for date you can use like `foo[1] = new Date();`