# How are the arrays structed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var A=[];
var B={C:"",D:[]};
A.push(B);
```

Can someone explain what's the difference between A and B arrays?If possible a scheme to understand it better.
Also i don't get why the code (B.C.length) gets as result the length of the first line  instead of the number of the objects the C array contains.

Comment: I feel like your question reflects a fundamental misunderstanding of the basics of javascript (A and B are not both arrays). Not only that, but I don't think you read the rules for what constitutes an appropriate question. I suggest searching up some basic tutorials on JavaScript on the site!

Comment: Well i am new to javascript.Can you point me some good tutorials?

Comment: Start with [this](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html)

Comment: @mic4ael thank you.I will study and i will stop asking foolish questions.

Comment: It's not a foolish question. Just make sure you research the question yourself before asking for help. And that doesn't just apply to SO.

Comment: duplicate of [What is the difference between these arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9307085/218196) and [What is the difference between an array and an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/874205/218196).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to learn a language from scratch. We expect that you already know the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this is an array
var a = [];  

// this is an object
var b = {};  

// this is an array of 2 objects
var c = [{}, {}];  

// this is an object with two properties, one of which is an array
var d = {x: [], y : "string"};  

// get number of elements in array
a.length;

// get length of string
d.y.length

// objects don't have length
b.length
```