# encapsulation in javascript module pattern

Tags: javascript, module, design-patterns, encapsulation

I was reading this link http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#modpattern

And saw the following example.

```
var basketModule = (function() {
var basket = []; //private

return { //exposed to public
       addItem: function(values) {
            basket.push(values);
        },
        getItemCount: function() {
            return basket.length;
        },
        getTotal: function(){
            var q = this.getItemCount(),p=0;
            while(q--){
                p+= basket[q].price;
            }
        return p;
        }
      }
}());

basketModule.addItem({item:'bread',price:0.5});
basketModule.addItem({item:'butter',price:0.3});

console.log(basketModule.getItemCount());
console.log(basketModule.getTotal());
```

It stats that "The module pattern is a popular design that pattern that encapsulates 'privacy', state and organization using closures" How is this different from writing it like the below?  Can't privacy be simply enforced with function scope?

```
var basketModule = function() {
var basket = []; //private
       this.addItem = function(values) {
            basket.push(values);
        }
        this.getItemCount = function() {
            return basket.length;
        }
        this.getTotal = function(){
            var q = this.getItemCount(),p=0;
            while(q--){
                p+= basket[q].price;
            }
        return p;
        }

}

var basket = new basketModule();

basket.addItem({item:'bread',price:0.5});
basket.addItem({item:'butter',price:0.3});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first variant you create an object without the possibility to create new instances of it (it is an immediately instantiated function). The second example is a full contructor function, allowing for several instances. The encapsulation is the same in both examples, the `basket` Array is 'private' in both.

Just for fun: best of both worlds could be:

```
var basketModule = (function() {
   function Basket(){
        var basket = []; //private
        this.addItem = function(values) {
            basket.push(values);
        }
        this.getItemCount = function() {
            return basket.length;
        }
        this.getTotal = function(){
            var q = this.getItemCount(),p=0;
            while(q--){
                p+= basket[q].price;
            }
        return p;
       }
     }
   return {
     basket: function(){return new Basket;}
   }
}());
//usage
var basket1 = basketModule.basket(), 
    basket2 = basketModule.basket(),
```

Comment: I guess my question is now is the first pattern more "module" than the second.  The link uses the first variant as an explicit example of the module pattern.

Comment: I'd say the first variant reflects the module pattern (delivering the `basketModule`), the second delivers a way to create `basket` *instances*. It's all a matter of labeling by the way, you could name the first variant also the 'singleton pattern'.

Comment: From the viewpoint that a module is an isolated package of functionality rather than a set of instantiatable classes, then yes.  However the difference between the two isn't so much design, it's syntax.  There's nothing stopping you from having a singleton the second way by having `var basketModule = new function(){...};`.  The idea of using a return object is that you can condense the interface into a few lines of code if you prefer, so you can see it at a glance.  But you wouldn't use large anonymous functions for this, you would just do `return {publicFunc:privateFunc};`.

Comment: @eirikrl when it comes to the new keyword take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful for a nice discussion on the topic. TL;DR there are a lot of ways to do things in JavaScript and most of them are not strictly wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks...perfect explanations :)