# In javascript, what happens when you new() a function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

I'm learning about prototypes in Javascript and wondered what this code is doing.  It's not like what I've run across in Java or C#:

```
  function MyObject(Parameter)
  {
    this.testString = Parameter;
  }

  var objectRef = new MyObject( "myValue" );
```

What's going on with that new MyObject("value") bit?  I understand that in javascript functions are objects, but I'm still wrapping my head around what's going on when you new() a function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful FFS I'm not going to be alowed to alter this shiza

Comment: good question, short:  No classes, only objects.  \n no sense?  Good, you are a java kid

Answer (score 2):

What its doing is the variable objectRef is creating a new object so everything in that function can be called on the variable affecting itself only. Let me give you a demonstration:

```
var cat = new MyObject("Im a cat");
var dog = new MyObject("Im a dog");

console.log(cat.testString);
// "Im a cat"

console.log(dog.testString);
// "Im a dog"
```

I hope that's of some help.