# How can anonymous event passing be achieved with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Desired scenario:

---

Within source file A.html, element A's onclick handler is coded to trigger a custom event every time A is clicked.

Within source file BCD.js elements B, C & D (which were unknown at the time that element A was coded) want to subscribe/handle/respond/react to the custom event triggered by A's onclick handler function.

---

In this case from A's perspective B, C & D are anonymous receivers of the custom event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement observer pattern in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308246/how-to-implement-observer-pattern-in-javascript)

Comment: Likewise, I'm having a hard time understanding what you example means. A html filename has nothing to do with any single element, and JavaScript has no HTML elements in it unless you first write code to make that happen, so: can you reword your question to use a less cryptic example, with normal names for things, and actual HTML and JS code you're imagining, so we can at least have something we can talk about in comments/answers?

Comment: No. In A's perspective, there are no B, C & D, there's just an element that an event can be triggered on. It does know nothing about subscribers.

Comment: this meets my need: http://jsfiddle.net/Neoheurist/ncv6ufkh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some sort of pubsub implementation.

```
var events = {};

var pubsub = {
    on: function(event, handler) {
        if(event in events) {
            events[event].push(handler);
        } else {
            events[event] = [handler];
        }
    },
    emit: function(event) {
        if(event in events) {
            events[event].forEach(function(handler) {
                handler.call(null, event);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

This sort of implementation ties custom events to a global object, so elements don't have to "know" about each other, like you mentioned. The way you'd implement the above would be something like:

```
document.getElementById('some-element').addEventListener('click', pubsub.emit.bind(null, 'custom-event'));
```

The click will emit an event, and any handlers will be called. So in some other module, or whatever, based on whatever action you prescribe, you can tie a handler to that event emission:

```
pubsub.on('custom-event', doSomething);

function doSomething() { ... }
```

I think this is a pretty normal, language-agnostic global event-handling implementation.

There are lots of ways that JavaScript developers have figured out how to handle this.

Comment: `document.getElementById('some-element')` ... does it matter which element the event listener is added to (e.g. are there scoping rules)? For instance if the event listener were added to a leaf `<p>` within the DOM would the visibility / accessibility be any different than if the event listener were attached to the `<body>` element? if it doesn't matter, what would be a best practice?

Comment: @Neoheurist, The native click event can only be seen by parents and children of the event target (events bubble up/down, depending on different circumstances.) However, the global event `custom-event` would be broadcast as part of the global `pubsub` object, which could be seen by, for example, a leaf `<p>` as you mention. Basically, by attaching the `pubsub` emission as a handler for the native `click`, you're forcing the click event to become "global", in a sense.

Comment: so the event listener can be attached to any element within the document. --- my inclination would be to add all event listeners to the `<body>` to emphasize the global scope (not that there would be any functional value to do this) --- does this sound reasonable?

Comment: @Neoheurist, what you're suggesting makes sense in a theoretical sense, but it almost seems like an anti-pattern to me in a practical sense. My gut tells me there would be a better way to do it. A lot of these problems have been solved by MVC frameworks, for example. What is it that you're trying to do exactly? Are you working on a project, or were you just looking at it in a theoretical sense?

Comment: It is a project and I'm on my own - so I apologize for picking nits - I have an edit button in a `<div>` that when clicked I want to activate an edit `<div>` by adding a class to it that causes the CSS to change the `<div>` from `display:none;` to `display:block;`... (changing any other `<div>` that might have been active to `display:none` in the process)

Comment: @Neoheurist, handlers can still select non-hierarchical elements. `$('#edit-button').on('click', function() { $('#editable-div').toggleClass('hidden'); })` would work (you don't have to use jQuery, I just used it for brevity).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80788/discussion-between-josh-beam-and-neoheurist).

Comment: I've embellished the approach provided by Josh Beam - the important part of the exercise was creating variable names to establish a solid mental model regarding what's happening in the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Neoheurist/ncv6ufkh/

Thanks again Josh!

Comment: @Neoheurist, interesting approach, I saw the jsfiddle! Glad you were able to find a way to make it work for you specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

First its important to differentiate between DOM events and the concept of events/pubsub in programming in general and the common javascript pattern.

DOM events are browser api to tell your javascript code that something have happened. they are also *asyc*

The custom events you are talking about are communication ways inside your javascript code, which is also referred to as 'events'
Heres a basic implementation of such pattern
http://davidwalsh.name/pubsub-javascript
In the underline code its a simple *sync* function call

One more thing:
technically you can trigger DOM events with custom names and use that to communicate between different parts of you javascript code. i would advise agains that.
That will also make the communication *async*