# backbone validate function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am using backbone validate function but it gives this error again `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'`. I really have no idea why is it giving me this error.

Here is my code

```
$(function () {
var Veh = new Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function (attrs) {
        var validColors = ['white','red', 'black'];
        var colorIsValid = function (attrs) {
            if(!attrs.color) return true;
            return _(validColors).include(attrs.color);
        }
        if(!colorIsValid(attrs)) {
            return 'wrong color';
        }
    }
});
var car = new Veh();
car.on('error', function (model, error) {
    console.log(error);
});
car.set('foo', 'bar');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: The error is the use of new. Don't do new when using Backbone.extend. This is because you are creating a class and not an object.

```
$(function () {
var Veh = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function (attrs) {
        var validColors = ['white','red', 'black'];
        var colorIsValid = function (attrs) {
            if(!attrs.color) return true;
            return _(validColors).include(attrs.color);
        }
        if(!colorIsValid(attrs)) {
            return 'wrong color';
        }
    }
});
```

Notice 
`var Veh = Backbone.Model.extend` instead of

```
var Veh = new Backbone.Model.extend
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful) question for the side effects of using new inadvertantly.

Comment: If you evaluate immediately with no parameters you will get an error immediately as attrs is not defined

Answer (score 1):

If you have the unminified version you can step through thte code and see where the error is. What I would do immediately, anyway, is change the param name of the `colorIsValid` function so it's not the same as the outer function...

```
validate: function (attrs) {
    var validColors = ['white','red', 'black'];
    var colorIsValid = function (modelAttrs) {
        if(!modelAttrs.color) return true;
        return _(validColors).include(modelAttrs.color);
    }
    if(!colorIsValid(attrs)) {
        return 'wrong color';
    }
}
```