# object literal notation - Should new be used or not

Tags: javascript

```
function foo() {
    return {a:9};
}

var bar = foo();
bar.a //returns 9
```

or

```
function foo() {
    return {a:9};
}

var bar = new foo(); 
bar.a // returns 9
```

As far as I know new isnt used with the object literal notation, but how come new does work with it? Also, why is it that prototype can be accessed with new object, but not with the object literal notation?

edit:

I understand it now, if anyone else who stumbles upon this problem/question this might help you understand it:

```
function foo() {
    this.a = "LOL";
    return "WTF";
};
var bar = new foo(); // bar = [Object object]
var c = foo(); // c = "WTF"
window.a // "LOL"
```

Also read the accepted answer.

Comment: Here's a good link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `new` in this circumstance has nothing to do with what you return, but what `this` is inside of `foo()`. Using `new`, `this` will be a reference to a foo instance inside of `foo()` . Without new, `this` will be the global (probably `window`)

Answer (score 5):

It works because if you explicitly return a non-primitive type from a function that is being called as a constructor (using `new`), then that object is returned instead of the created object. You are not using the created object in your function in any way, so `new` is redundant.

Here you can see that it doesn't work with primitives:

```
function test() {
    return "string"; //This is not returned when called with new, because it's primitive
}

var a = new test();
a == "string" // false

function test() {
    return new String("string"); //This is returned when called with new, because it's an object, like {}
}

var b = new test();
b == "string" //true
```

I am using `==` and `new String` for demonstration purposes. You should never use `new String` in practice.

Comment: Too bad I cant accept two answers. I was confused about two different things. Thanks for your input.

Comment: +1 wow that's confusing (I mean the behavior, not the explanation)

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is just a short cut for `new Object()`

Comment: Sort of, but there is technically a difference.

Comment: I hate to mark someone down ... but that's just not accurate.  Sorry :(  See Brian Cray's and Esailja's responses.

Comment: Like what? `({}).constructor === Object`

Comment: `{}` works even if `Object` is set to `null`. `Object = null;
new Object();
TypeError: object is not a function` `var a = {}; a.constructor === Object; //false`

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf page 65
The production  ObjectLiteral :  { }  is evaluated as follows:
1. Return a new object created as if by the expression new Object() where Object is the standard builtin constructor with that name

Comment: Yes, but in practice that easily leads to a security flaw that gmail once had.