# Javascript 'new' with function returning self-defined object

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the following function:

```
var A = function() {
   var label = "hello";
   return {
      getLabel: function() { return label; }
   }
};
```

Is there any difference between:

```
var a = A();
```

and

```
var a = new A();
```

?

NB: I'm not asking here [what is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript), but how it behaves in this particular example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: please go through this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: Yes I've already read it. i was just wondering if there was any difference in this particular example

Comment: @fmsf the question is about the given example, that's why I posted it despite the existence of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: That whole ***new*** thing [is answered here][1] and [ also here][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful

Comment: @GhoulFool is it irrelevant to ask how the `new` thing applies in a specific context ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your particular instance, *No*, there is no difference.

Eitherw way, your function will return a *self defined Object*. By invoking a function with the `new` keyword, ECMAscript will automatically create a new object for you (alongside doing some magic with `prototype` and `constructor` properties), which you might *access* / *write to* via `this` within the `function (-constructor)`.

Again, your `return { }` call in that function, will always return exactly that object reference.

Comment: +1 - Example of where it does matter here: http://jsfiddle.net/9Xcbr/