# function returning dictionary - is 'new' needed or not?

Tags: javascript

considering:

```js
function C() {
  var v=5;
  
  function getV() { return v; }
  
  return {
    getV: getV
   }
 }

var o1=new C();
alert(o1.getV());

var o2=C();
alert(o2.getV());
```

As both versions produce the same result

- what is the difference between the version using new and the version that doesn't ?
- is any version better ?

Comment: 1 - yes there is a difference, 2 - better for what purpose?

Comment: what's the difference pls ?

Comment: This question will help you out a lot: [what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson - champion, I was just beginning to look for an old answer

Comment: yes but in this case they do exactly the same ?

Comment: @kofifus They **don't** do the same thing. But your output will be the same in this case.

Comment: well thx for not helping :(

Comment: @kofifus ... I answered your question. What more do you want?

Comment: If you don't need to use `C.prototype` or `this` inside the function, then using `new` here may be misleading. Voting to close as duplicate - the other question has super comprehensive explanations.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new

Comment: A more exact duplicate (with a direct answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747325/javascript-new-with-function-returning-self-defined-object?noredirect=1